# Why is the size not a template argument of std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

`std::initializer_list` is constructed by the compiler from a brace-enclosed init list and the size of this list must be a compile time constant.

So why did the committee decide to omit the size from the template arguments? This possibly prevents some optimizations and makes some things impossible (initializing `std::array` from a `std::initializer_list`).

Comment: A very similar question is "why is `std::initializer_list::size` not `constexpr` (anymore) ?" which was asked on clc++m a year ago.

Comment: Re MSalters' 2011 comment, notice that C++14 *does* make `std::initializer_list::size` a `constexpr` function, even though C++11 didn't. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/size

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One upside of the existing system is that you can export functions which take an `initializer_list` from a DLL. If it were templated on the size, they would have to be shipped as source.

Comment: Along the same lines: it can cause some non-trivial bloat.

Answer (score 15):

If `initializer_list` was defined as `std::initializer_list<type, size>`, then *any* function that takes an `initializer_list<type>`, where `type` is some concrete type, would now have to be a template function based on that list's size. Or they would have to require that users pass an `initializer_list` of a specific type *and size*.

Both of these are pretty unacceptable. Not everyone writes all of their code as templates.

You can initialize a `std::array` from a braced-init-list (`{}` with stuff in the middle). But that's not the same thing as a `std::intiializer_list`. The `array` class is an aggregate type. It is a struct that contains a single element, which is a public array. Therefore, on a conforming C++11 implementations, this should compile:

```
std::array<int, 3> myArray = {1, 3, 5};
```

However, `{1, 3, 5}` is not a `std::initializer_list` object; it is merely a braced-init-list, which can be used to initialize appropriate types.

You cannot pass a `std::initializer_list` object to the constructor of an aggegate (because aggregates have no constructors), but you can use a braced-init-list to invoke aggregate initialization to initialize a `std::array`, just as you would for any struct containing an array.

The difference between a `std::initializer_list` and a braced-init-list is a bit like the difference between an `int` and the literal `0`. It's not (usually) legal to implicitly convert an `int` object into a pointer type, but it is legal to implicitly convert an integer literal 0 into a pointer type. The way braced-init-lists work is like that:

```
int i = 0;    //Legal
void *j = 0;  //Legal
void *k = i;  //Not legal

std::array<int, 3> myArray = {1, 3, 5};             //Legal
std::initializer_list<int> myInitList = {1, 3, 5};  //Legal
std::array<int, 3> myArray = myInitList;            //Not legal
```

Comment: Are you sure about initializing `std::array` from `std::initializer_list`? `array<int, 3> x = {1,2,3}` does not work on gcc 4.6 and I cannot infer that this should work from n3242.

Comment: @pmr: std::array is defined (in N3291) as a struct, and it follows the C++0x rules for an aggregate type. Therefore, it should be initialized via aggregate initialization. So you initialize it as though it were a struct holding an array of 3 elements. I'll update my post to explain this.

Comment: @Nicol : That's just aggregate initialization -- `initializer_list` is completely orthogonal.

Comment: @ildjarn: Technically, yes. But users don't care if it uses a `std::initializer_list` object or aggregates or whatever; all they care about is that it *works*. That they can use {} syntax to statically initialize a `std::array`.

Comment: @Nicol : They do for purposes of e.g. writing a `make_array` function, as has been brought up multiple times on SO. In any case, I find it misleading to say "*You can initialize a `std::array` from an initializer list*" when what you really mean is just that `std::array` can be initialized with superficially similar syntax.

Comment: @ildjarn: Which is why the statement is followed by "sort of" and doesn't mention `std::initializer_list` the type, but simply "an initializer list". Notice the lack of an underscore.

Comment: What I'm wondering is that why one allowed to instantiate std::initializer_list without size requirements if its a statically allocated struct? Or is it dynamically allocated?

Comment: @glades: `initializer_list` is not "statically allocated". The array that `initializer_list` *references* may be statically allocated. It is at the very least local to the context which contains the braced-init-list.