# Why isn't std::initializer_list a language built-in?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, initializer-list

### Why isn't `std::initializer_list` a core-language built-in?

It seems to me that it's quite an important feature of C++11 and yet it doesn't have its own reserved keyword (or something alike).

Instead, `initializer_list` it's *just* a template class from the standard library that has a special, implicit *mapping* from the new *braced-init-list* `{...}` syntax that's handled by the compiler.

At first thought, this solution is quite *hacky*.

Is this the way new additions to the C++ language will be now implemented: by **implicit roles** of some template classes and not by the **core** language?

---

**Please consider these examples:**

```
   widget<int> w = {1,2,3}; //this is how we want to use a class
```

why was a new class chosen:

```
   widget( std::initializer_list<T> init )
```

instead of using something **similar** to any of these ideas:

```
   widget( T[] init, int length )  // (1)
   widget( T... init )             // (2)
   widget( std::vector<T> init )   // (3)
```

1. a classic array, you could probably add `const` here and there
2. three dots already exist in the language (var-args, now variadic templates), why not re-use the syntax (and make it feel *built-in*)
3. just an existing container, could add `const` and `&`

All of them are already a part of the language. I only wrote my 3 first ideas, I am sure that there are **many** other approaches.

Comment: The standards committee *hate* adding new keywords!

Comment: This I understand, but there are many possibilities how to extend the language (*keyword was just an example*)

Comment: So you would be ok with `std::array` but not with `std::initializer_list`? They have different semantics, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: `std::array<T>` is no more 'part of the language' than `std::initializer_list<T>`. And these are not nearly the only library components that the language relies on. See `new`/`delete`, `type_info`, various exception types, `size_t`, etc.

Comment: @Elmes: I would have suggested `const T(*)[N]`, because that behaves very similarly to how `std::initializer_list` works.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108425/why-is-the-size-not-a-template-argument-of-stdinitializer-list) answers why `std::array` or a statically-sized array are less desirable alternatives.

Comment: I read all comments and answers, and found exactly the same discussion here: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2215.pdf 

If anyone is interested, pls check "4.5 The initializer_list class"
• Is initializer_list a keyword? No, but.
• Must I #include a header to use initializer_list? Yes, #include<initializer_list>
• Why don’t we use a constructor that takes a general STL sequence?
• Why don’t we use a general standard library class (e.g. Range or Array)?
• Why don’t we use T(&)[N]?
• Why don’t we use T[N]?
• Can the size() be a constant expression? Yes

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There were already examples of "core" language features that returned types defined in the `std` namespace. `typeid` returns `std::type_info` and (stretching a point perhaps) `sizeof` returns `std::size_t`.

In the former case, you already need to include a standard header in order to use this so-called "core language" feature.

Now, for initializer lists it happens that no keyword is needed to generate the object, the syntax is context-sensitive curly braces. Aside from that it's the same as `type_info`. Personally I don't think the absence of a keyword makes it "more hacky". Slightly more surprising, perhaps, but remember that the objective was to allow the same braced-initializer syntax that was already allowed for aggregates.

So yes, you can probably expect more of this design principle in future:

- if more occasions arise where it is possible to introduce new features without new keywords then the committee will take them.
- if new features require complex types, then those types will be placed in `std` rather than as builtins.

Hence:

- if a new feature requires a complex type and can be introduced without new keywords then you'll get what you have here, which is "core language" syntax with no new keywords and that uses library types from `std`.

What it comes down to, I think, is that there is no absolute division in C++ between the "core language" and the standard libraries. They're different chapters in the standard but each references the other, and it has always been so.

There is another approach in C++11, which is that lambdas introduce objects that have *anonymous* types generated by the compiler. Because they have no names they aren't in a namespace at all, certainly not in `std`. That's not a suitable approach for initializer lists, though, because you use the type name when you write the constructor that accepts one.

Comment: It seems to me that this division is not possible (mailny?) because of such *implicit* roles of types. `type_info` and `size_t` are nice arguments.. well `size_t` is just a typedef.. so let's skip this. The difference between `type_info` and `initializer_list` is that the first is a result of an *explicit* operator, and the second of an *implicit* compiler action. It also seems to me, that `initializer_list` *could* be replaced with some already existing containers.. or yet better: any the user declares as argument type!

Comment: @elmes: I don't see any significant difference between what you call an explicit operator and what you call an implicit compiler action. They're both just syntax understood by the compiler, they're both "core" to the language. And I don't think it would change your question if initializer list syntax resulted in a `const std::array` (or something) instead of a `std::initializer_list`, they're both types in the standard library. If it's true that `const std::array` would do, it might even just be because they're both new and were considered separately.

Comment: ... or it might be the simple reason that if you wrote a constructor for `vector` that takes an `array` then you could construct a vector from *any* array of the right type, not just one generated by the initializer list syntax. I'm not sure it would be a bad thing to construct containers from any `array`, but it's not the intent of the committee in introducing the new syntax.

Comment: I partially agree with you. Why do you think C++ has var-args, now variadic templates and .. initializer list..? Don't you see a bit of inconsistency here? My original question's intent was to understand why the committee choose the last approach..

Comment: @elmes: "An array of stuff" and "a list to initialize stuff with" are *fundamentally* different concepts. I see no reason why the two should share the same type. Also, wrt "any the user declares as argument type!" - if you have `int x{5};`, there is no `std::initializer_list` *ever* involved. Same goes for your types if they happen to have a matching constructor for what's written inside the braces.

Comment: @elmes Well ok, varargs are a relict of *C* and not really needed since variadic templates are out (who used them before anyway? except for the occassional evil `printf` maybe). But with just using variadic templates, you e.g. cannot do `for(auto i : {1,2,3}) ...`, without maybe introducing some temporary type (like a `std::array(1, 2, 3)`) that, in constrast to an implicit `initializer_list`, would copy those values (no matter what your super-optimizing compiler really does). And just defaulting a `{}` to a `array` wouldn't be different from an `ilist` (except for the disadvantages mentioned)

Comment: @ChristianRau: `std::initializer_list` copies all the elements just the same.

Comment: @Xeo Really? Isn't it just a lightweight container-view into some non-specified storage area (which might need copying itself if the values are dynamically determined, but might also just be static storage like in my `{1,2,3}` example)?

Comment: @Christian: No, the standard explicitly says that all arguments are copied. You also can't create an `initializer_list` of move-only types.

Comment: @Xeo Wow, two O(n) copies for a simple `std::array<int,N> a = { ... }`? That's bad news!

Comment: @Christian: No, `std::array` doesn't even have any constructors. The `std::array` case is simply aggregate-initialization. Also, I welcome you to join me in the Lounge<C++> chat room, since this discussion is getting a bit long.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Xeo means elements are copied when the initializer list is constructed.  Copying an initializer list doesn't copy contained elements.

Comment: @Christian List-initialisation does not imply initializer_list. It can be many things, including good ole direct-initialisation, or aggregate initialisation. None of those involve initializer_list (and some just *cannot* work that way).

Comment: @SteveJessop this is the most complete answer so far, I accept it (for now ;-)

Answer (score 42):

The C++ Standard Committee seems to prefer not to add new keywords, probably because that increases the risk of breaking existing code (legacy code could use that keyword as the name of a variable, a class, or whatever else).

Moreover, it seems to me that defining `std::initializer_list` as a templated container is quite an elegant choice: if it was a keyword, how would you access its underlying type? How would you iterate through it? You would need a bunch of new operators as well, and that would just force you to remember more names and more keywords to do the same things you can do with standard containers.

Treating an `std::initializer_list` as any other container gives you the opportunity of writing generic code that works with any of those things.

**UPDATE:**

> Then why introduce a new type, instead of using some combination of existing? *(from the comments)*

To begin with, all others containers have methods for adding, removing, and emplacing elements, which are not desirable for a compiler-generated collection. The only exception is `std::array<>`, which wraps a fixed-size C-style array and would therefore remain the only reasonable candidate.

However, as [**Nicol Bolas**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas) correctly points out in the comments, another, fundamental difference between `std::initializer_list` and all other standard containers (including `std::array<>`) is that the latter ones have *value semantics*, while `std::initializer_list` has *reference semantics*. Copying an `std::initializer_list`, for instance, won't cause a copy of the elements it contains.

Moreover (once again, courtesy of Nicol Bolas), having a special container for brace-initialization lists allows overloading on the way the user is performing initialization.

Comment: Then why introduce a new type, instead of using some combination of existing?

Comment: @elmes: Not sure I understand. Do you mean, "why not mapping brace lists into a vector"?

Comment: Yes, for why not vector (for example)?

Comment: @elmes: `vector` and other containers also support methods for adding, altering, and removing elements, which you do not want with an initializer list

Comment: This isn't necessarily wrong. You could always declare a `const vector` or even a `vector&&`

Comment: @elmes: Actually it is more like `std::array`. But `std::array` allocates memory while `std::initializaer_list` wraps a compile-time array. Think of it as the difference between `char s[] = "array";` and `char *s = "initializer_list";`.

Comment: @rodrigo: `std::array<>` also allows modifying the values it contains, like a C-style array. `initializer_list` is immutable.

Comment: And having being it a _normal_ type makes overloading, template specialization, name-decoration and the like, non-issues.

Comment: @rodrigo: `std::array` doesn't allocate any memory, it's a plain `T arr[N];`, the same thing that is backing `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @Xeo: `T arr[N]` _does allocate_ memory, maybe not in the dynamic heap but elsewhere... So does `std::array`. However a non-empty `initializer_list` cannot be constructed by the user so it obviously cannot allocate memory.

Comment: @elmes An `initializer_list` isn't really a container (in that it contains actual data), but rather a container-view into some (not really specified) constant storage area that holds the actual data, so it isn't like any other container around. Though, they maybe could have defined that storage area to be a `std::array` of values in the first place, but I'm not completely sure about the implications of this approach...

Comment: @elmes ...But then you would have a container, which is **both** an actual container for usual container purposes **and** a special *"languagy thing"* related to a special language feature. With `std::initializer_list` you have such a special thing to be used with brace-lists, which on the other hand **cannot** be used as a regular container. Don't underestimate proper separation of concerns.

Comment: "*Then why introduce a new type, instead of using some combination of existing?*" Because there is no existing type which has all of the properties of `std::initializer_list`. `vector` and `array` (and all other containers) use  value-semantics; `initializer_list` uses reference-semantics. Copying an `initializer_list` does not copy its elements. Plus, if it is a separate type, it can be used in overload resolution to tell the difference between a user who use a `{}` and a user who just happened to use a `const vector`.

Comment: So it comes down to a simple answer: a type instead of syntax, because it's safer. `initializer_list` instead of anything else, because it's more appropriate to this task. Okay. This sounds quite complete. Only question in my mind is: why the inconsistency? Why do variadic templates (or choose something else here) introduce new syntax, and uniform initialization doesn't?

Answer (score 6):

This is nothing new. For example, `for (i : some_container)` relies on [existence of specific methods or standalone functions](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html) in `some_container` class. C# even relies even more on its .NET libraries. Actually, I think, that this is quite an elegant solution, because you can make your classes compatible with some language structures without complicating language specification.

Comment: methods in class **or** stand-alone `begin` and `end` methods. This is  a bit different IMO.

Comment: Is it? Again you have a pure language construct relying on specific construction of your code. It also might have been done by introducing new keyword, for instance, `iterable class MyClass { };`

Comment: but you can place the methods wherever you want, implement them however you want.. There is some similarity, I agree! This question is about `initializer_list` though

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed nothing new and how many have pointed out, this practice was there in C++ and is there, say, in C#.

Andrei Alexandrescu has mentioned a good point about this though: You may think of it as a part of imaginary "core" namespace, then it'll make more sense.

So, it's actually something like: `core::initializer_list`, `core::size_t`, `core::begin()`, `core::end()` and so on. This is just an unfortunate coincidence that `std` namespace has some core language constructs inside it.

Answer (score 2):

Not only can it work completely in the standard library. Inclusion into the standard library does not mean that the compiler can not play clever tricks.

While it may not be able to in all cases, it may very well say: this type is well known, or a simple type, lets ignore the `initializer_list` and just have a memory image of what the initialized value should be.

In other words `int i {5};` can be equivalent to `int i(5);` or `int i=5;` or even `intwrapper iw {5};` Where `intwrapper` is a simple wrapper class over an int with a trivial constructor taking an `initializer_list`

Comment: Do we have reproducible examples of compilers actually playing "clever tricks" like this? It kinda stands to reason under _as-if_, but I'd like to see substantiation.

Comment: The idea of optimizing compilers is that the compiler can transform the code to any equivalent code. C++ in particular relies on optimisation for "free" abstractions. The idea of replacing code from the standard library is common (look at the gcc builtin list https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

Comment: In fact, your idea that `int i {5}` involves any `std::initializer_list` is wrong. `int` has no constructor taking `std::initializer_list`, so the `5` is just used directly to construct it. So the main example is irrelevant; there is simply no optimisation to be done. Beyond that, since `std::initializer_list` involves the compiler creating and proxying an 'imaginary' array, I guess it can favour optimisation, but that's the 'magic' part in the compiler, so it's separate from whether the optimiser in general can do anything clever with the pretty dull object containing 2 iterators that results

Answer (score 1):

It's not part of the core language because it can be implemented entirely in the library, just line `operator new` and `operator delete`. What advantage would there be in making compilers more complicated to build it in?