# C++ SFINAE double nested initializer_list vs. variadic template constructor

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, sfinae, initializer-list

### Problem

I am writing a small math library that has `Vector` and `Matrix` classes. I'd like to make it convenient to intialize objects of these classes with **strict rules** for how they can be initialized.

The `Vector` class constructor already works as i intended. It is restricted such that only the correct size `N` is accepted and on top of that all arguments are of the same type (see below).

`Vector`

```
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
class Vector{
  public:
    template <typename... TArgs,
            std::enable_if_t<
                sizeof...(TArgs) == N &&
                    (std::is_same_v<T, std::remove_reference_t<TArgs>> && ...),int> = 0>
    Vector(TArgs &&... args) : data_{std::forward<TArgs>(args)...} {}

    // ...

  private:
    std::array<T,N> data;
}
```

Example initialization (works, is restricted)

```
Vector<3,int> v{1,2,3}
```

`Matrix`

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t M, typename T>
class Matrix{
  public:
    /* put restriction rules here */
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> lst) {
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      for (const auto &l : lst) {
        for (const auto &v : l) {
          data[i][j] = v;
          ++j;
        }
        j = 0;
        ++i;
      }
    }

    // ...

  private:
    std::array<Vector<M, T>, N> data;
}
```

Example initialization 1 (works, is not restricted)

```
Matrix<2,3,int> m{ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} }
```

Example initialization 2 (compiles, but shouldn't!!)

```
Matrix<2,3,int> m{ {1,'a',3}, {4,5,6,7,8,9} }
```

### Question

I wasn't able to implement the `Matrix` class constructor for the double-nested initialization with a variadic template, so i used nested `std::initializer_list`´s (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810171/is-there-a-way-to-pass-nested-initializer-lists-in-c11-to-construct-a-2d-matri) post). It works, but i'd like to have the same restrictions on this constructor as for the `Vector` class.

How can i do this?

- the list size must be N (rows)
- the list-list size must always be M (columns)
- the encapsulated value type must always be T

### additional info

regarding this post here... [::std::initializer_list vs variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139379/stdinitializer-list-vs-variadic-templates) i can say that i don't really care for using initializer_list or a variadic template. Either one seems fine in this case, but as far as i understand getting the size of an `std::initializer_list` at compile time is somewhat difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have you desired syntax, you might do:

```
template <typename ... Us,
          std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Us) == N && (std::is_same_v<Us, T> && ...), int> = 0>
Matrix(const Us (&... rows)[M]) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simple make `Matrix` take a 2D array reference as such:

```
Matrix(T const (&m)[N][M])
```

This will only compile under the conditions you specify and adapting the rest of your code is also easy. You can apply the same principle to simplify `Vector`.

Comment: with this solution i would need an extra pair of braces when initializing: `Matrix<2,3,int> m{ { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} } }` and also something like the 'a' is not prevented. (I suppose the latter can be corrected with a template restriction on T.) If possible, i'd prefer not having to write out an extra pair of braces

Comment: @mtosch: I can see the braces thing, but why would you even want to prevent passing e.g. characters? That seems too restrictive to me, e.g. if i want to brace-initialize a `std::vector<int>` I can also pass anything that is implicitly convertible to `int`.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the braces, I suppose you could use the variadic template approach in combination with array references.

Comment: what's the syntax for combining variadic template ... with array references? I can't seem to get it right. I can do it with an initializer list easily: `template <typename... TArgs>Matrix(std::initializer_list<TArgs> &&... args)`

Comment: Ok, just figured it out: `template<typename... TArgs>Matrix(TArgs const (&... args)[M])`
It is mentioned in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack under "Function parameter list"