# When to use initializer list constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

Using `{}` instead of `()` in a constructor will allow me to initialize class members with a specific constructor right in the header, like so:

```
class X {
    private:
        std::vector y{1, 2, 3};
};
```

But how do I know that for a class `Z` I use `Z z{a, b};` will call the constructor that has two parameters — `Z::Z(int a, int b)` — and not the one with the `std::initializer_list`?

I mean `std::complex(1, 2)` and `std::complex{1, 2}` are the same, but `std::vector(3)` and `std::vector{3}` are certainly not.

Should I always use the `{}` variant or use `()` unless I need `{}`?

Comment: Personally, I usually use curly braces to indicate that an initialization argument is _data_ to be contained or managed, or an object to be linked (for example, `std::vector<int> {4, 5}`, `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> {my_mutex}`, or `std::istream_iterator<int> {std::cin}`). For _logical_ or descriptive arguments, I use parentheses, e.g. `std::uniform_int_distribution<> (0, 99)` or `std::regex ("foo")`. This is a stylistic guideline, though, so YMMV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a topic that can span an entire book chapter. See a quote from [**this recent draft Item**](http://aristeia.com/EC++11-14/parens%20or%20braces%202014-03-18.pdf) by Scott Meyers of his upcoming Effective Modern C++ (reformatted for clarity):

> Most developers end up choosing one kind of delimiter as a default,
>   using the other only when they have to.
>
> - Braces-by-default folks are attracted by their wide applicability,
>     their prevention of [**narrowing conversions**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4434140/819272), and their avoidance of
>     C++’s [**most vexing parse**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/180172/819272). Such folks understand that in some cases
>     (e.g., creation of a `std::vector` with a given size and initial element
>     value), parentheses are required.
> - In contrast, the go-parentheses-go crowd embraces parentheses as their
>     default argument delimiter. They’re attracted to its consistency with
>     the C++98 syntactic tradition, its avoidance of the
>     [**auto-deduced-a-`std::initializer_list` problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17105849/819272), and the knowledge that
>     their object creation calls won’t be [**inadvertently waylaid by
>     `std::initializer_list` constructors**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847960/which-greedy-initializer-list-examples-are-lurking-in-the-standard-library). They concede that sometimes only
>     braces will do (e.g., when creating a container with particular
>     values).
>
> **Neither approach is rigorously better than the other**. My advice is to
>   pick one and apply it consistently.

Comment: Interesting read. I currently have the feeling that the `{}` only shifted the problem around :-/

Comment: @queueoverflow not entirely, there previously was no way to directly initialize Standard containers, e.g.. But you are right, there are still some minor warts with `{}` initialization.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is that if a class has a constructor that takes an `initializer_list`, and the elements in your *braced-init-list* are convertible (remember that braced-init-lists do not allow narrowing conversions) to the `initializer_list`'s argument type, then the constructor that takes the `initializer_list` will *always* be called. Otherwise the compiler will attempt to match other constructors.

In case of an empty braced-init-list the default constructor is called, assuming one is accessible.

There is no simple answer to your question about whether parentheses should be preferred over braces, or vice versa, for initialization. In hindsight, `vector`'s constructors are a bad design choice because it can be made to behave unexpectedly, at least to the uninitiated, quite trivially.

Comment: vector's constructors were ok, it is list-initialization which has "bad design choice"