# How to make my own initializer_list class in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I made a class that has the same implementation of `std::initializer_list` using VS2013 that supports `Uniform Initialization.`

```
template <class _Elem>
class My_Initializer_List { ... } // Hope to replace std::initializer_list!
```

The first thing I've noticed is that the compiler keeps looking for `std::initializer_list` when it does have the substitute for it, which is `My_Initiliazer_List`.

```
void Foo()
{
    // The compiler tries to invoke 
    // its constructor with std::initializer<int>{ 10, 20 }.
    auto MyVar = My_Initializer_List<int>{ 10, 20 }; // Compile Error!
}
```

If this feature depends on the C++ Standard Library, then I believe that I should be able to replace it with my own class, at least for academic purposes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't implement it

Comment: @aaronman Thanks again. But could you be a little more specific about why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementation of std::initializer\_list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164353/implementation-of-stdinitializer-list)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, but no. The compiler has special knowledge of `std::initializer_list` "baked in". The same is true of a few other parts of the standard library (e.g., a `dynamic_cast` of a reference throws a `std::bad_cast`, and there's not really anything you can do to change that either).

Comment: This is most unfortunate, in my opinion.

Comment: Saying no include is needed to create instances is wrong. **8.5.4.2**: "_The template `std::initializer_list` is not predefined; if the header `<initializer_list>` is not included prior to a use of `std::initializer_list`—even an implicit use in which the type is not named (7.1.6.4)—the program is ill-formed._" e.g. with just a `for` over `{some, ints}`, `g++` 8 errors. Sure, a class taking `initializer_list` must itself include it & it's OK to rely transitively on that. Beyond that, it's bad to rely on indirect includes from other headers, especially if (I'm unsure) no diagnostic is required.