# How to define initializer list constructor without using std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++

I want to make a small library of my own containers without relying on STL at all, as a form of exercise. How can I define an initializer list constructor for my classes without std::initializer_list? How is it even implemented?

Comment: Long story short - you can't. `std::vector` couldn't, you can't do it general case either. There is a reason why `std::initializer_list` exists.

Comment: Well that sucks

Comment: Because of the way the was the language works `{ stuff }` doesn't actually have a type.  It takes the compiler to do some "magic" to turn that *braced-init-list* into a `std::initializer_list`.  You would have to make your own compiler to provide your own "magic".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementation of std::initializer\_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164353/implementation-of-stdinitializer-list)

Comment: `<initializer_list>` is guaranteed to be available on freestanding implementations, so there is no reason to avoid it.

Comment: An "initializer list constructor" *implies* use of `std::initializer_list`.  Yet you want to *not* use `std::initializer_list`? Sorry. Your question makes no sense to me.

Comment: "want to make a small library of my own containers without relying on STL at all" - Why? Why would you *not* take advantage of the library that has already been developed and debugged by experts and is available with every C++ implementation and instead develop your own library that *almost certainly* will be inferior? Why? Sounds like a enormous waste of time to me.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You seem to have missed those few words after a comma

Comment: @Big yes, you are right. I did miss that. As an exercise it's obviously OK. Just don't do that for production code..

Comment: @JesperJuhl I won't, I promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I define an initializer list constructor for my classes without `std::initializer_list`?

You don't. The very definition of "initializer list constructor" is tied into `std::initializer_list`. Just like the result of `typeid` is tied directly into `std::type_info`, and the result of `sizeof` and `alignof` is a `std::size_t`.

Attempting to use C++ while pretending the standard library in its entirety does not exist is folly. There are parts of it you can ignore without consequence, but if you want to have an "initializer list constructor", you have to use `std::initializer_list`.

The C++ standard library is not *optional*; it is not divorced from C++ as a langauge. Parts of it are, but `std::initializer_list` isn't one of those parts.

Comment: Why did they have to invent something called `initalizer_list` instead of reusing `std::vector` or `std::array`? Something like `{ 1, 2, 3 }` means `std::vector<int>` which contains 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: @Ayxan because `std::vector<int>` implies dynamic allocation, and `std::array<int, 3>` ties the number of elements into the type. `std::initalizer_list` is a temporary with unspecified size

Comment: @Caleth is `std::initalizer_list` stack allocated?

Comment: @Ayxan: `std::initializer_list` is just a pair of pointers. The temporary it refers to is a temporary.

Comment: @NicolBolas are the pointers pointing to dynamic memory? Is it specified at all?

Comment: [Temporary Object Lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime)

Comment: @Ayxan: It's a temporary array. The array follows the rules of temporaries.