# C++11 Implicit conversion from initialization list to array parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initializer-list

In C++11, is it possible to do something similar to the following?

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void foo(array<T, N> src) { ... }

...

foo({1, 2, 3})
```

I'm currently running GCC 4.8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, I managed to get the following work (since you allow *something similar*):

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void foo(array<T, N> src) { ... }

...

foo('a', 'b');
foo(1, 2, 3);
```

Here is how:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, unsigned long N>
void foo(array<T,N> src) { 

  for (auto e : src)
    cout << e << endl;
}

template<class T, class... Tail>
auto make_array(T head, Tail... tail) -> std::array<T, 1 + sizeof...(Tail)>
{
     std::array<T, 1 + sizeof...(Tail)> a = {{ head, tail ... }};
     return a;
}

template<class T, class... Tail> 
void foo(T&& head, Tail&&... values) {

    foo(make_array(std::forward<T>(head), std::forward<Tail>(values)...));
}

int main() {

  foo('a', 'b');

  foo(1, 2, 3);
}
```

I have tested this with gcc 4.7.2 and with clang 3.4 (trunk 184647), they work as expected.
Here is an online version [at Stacked-Crooked.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6763ae9f3d248efc1e32110937109c21-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51) However, this code fails to compile at Ideone. Since I was unable to figure out the options passed to the compiler at Ideone, I've given up on that site.

---

I have shamelessly stolen the `make_array` function from [@Pavel Minaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111335/pavel-minaev)'s answer to the [How to emulate C array initialization “int arr[] = { e1, e2, e3, … }” behaviour with std::array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114299/341970) question. The other `make_array` suggestions caused compile errors that I couldn't fix.

This `make_array` function has limitations, please read [the entire post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6114067/341970); in particular the discussion [std::array - if only it knew its size](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/8aWhRRsAO-w) on comp.lang.c++.moderated is referenced. Apparently, getting a reasonable `make_array` is quite tricky. **I wouldn't recommend the simple-minded `make_array` in this answer to be used in production code.**

---

You wouldn't have any problems if the size was a template argument to `std::initializer_list`. Hence the question [Why is the size not a template argument of std::initializer_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7108425/341970)

Comment: Impressive... I think I need to read up some more to understand that `make_array`... :)

Comment: **Why the downvote?** What is wrong with the answer? The OP allows for *something similar*.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently not. The standard (14.8.2.5) calls this an non-deduced context;

> In certain contexts, however, the value does not participate in type deduction, but instead uses the values of template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly speciﬁed.
>
> ...
>
> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> ...
>
> - A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list (8.5.4) but the parameter does not have std::initializer_list or reference to possibly cv-qualiﬁed std::initializer_list type.
>
> Example:
>
> template<class T> void g(T);
>   g({1,2,3}); // error: no argument deduced for T

EDIT: You *can* make the same thing work with `std::vector`, if you just use an `initializer_list` overload to make the deduction of the *type* work;

```c++
template<typename T>
  void foo(const std::vector<T>& src) { ...your code here... }
template<typename T>
  void foo(const std::initializer_list<T>& src) { foo(std::vector<T>(src)); }

foo({1,2,3});  // Compiles
```

...but sadly, since the size of `initializer_list` is not a template argument, I can't think of a way to make it deduce and forward the array *size* from the `initializer_list` in the same way as the type.

Comment: The vector solution seems to work without an initializer_list overload.

Comment: @jameszhao00 On which gcc? I only have 4.7.3 to test on currently. EDIT: Ah, 4.8, didn't see that you were the one asking the question :)

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use an initializer list directly to achieve that syntax. e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

void foo(std::initializer_list<int> il) {
  for (auto i: il)
    std::cout << i < std::endl;
}

int main() {
  foo({1,2,3});
}
```

or make it more generic:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(std::initializer_list<T> il) {
  ...
```

Comment: Going even further, why not template `foo` to any container?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with references to raw arrays:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t N>
void foo(T const (&x)[N]) {
    // x is [1, 2, 3], N = 3
}

int main() {
    foo({1, 2, 3});
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the array *must* be declared `const`.

Comment: This is nice. Do you have any insight why `const` allows this implicit conversion, and if so, please share it?

Comment: Is it because the reference must be const?

Comment: I don't know. I just read it in the "C++ Templates" book.

Comment: I believe I have the same book. Tons of stuff about array and pointer decay. Do you remember the section?

Comment: Sections 5.4 and 7.4 from the 2nd edition, I think