# array length deduction from argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, stdarray

Given a function with the parameter signature `std::array<const size_t, V> shape` like:

```
template<int V>
struct Cls {int val(){return V;} };


template <int V>
auto make(std::array<const size_t, V> shape) -> Cls<V>{
  return Cls<V>();
}
```

I need to always add the template parameter `V` like

```
auto t1 = make<2>({2, 3}); // does work but need the information twice
std::cout << t1.val() << std::endl;
```

as the braced-initializer list seems to be casted into a c++11 `std::array`. However, this seems to me redundant. The length of `{2, 3}` is two. I know it and the compiler should also know it. Is it possible to wrap it into:

```
// auto t0 = make({2, 3}); // doesn't work
// auto t0 = make(2, 3); // would be also ok
```

I tried something like determining the size of the `std::array` as a `constexpr`. But I can't get rid of the template argument `<2>`.

```
template <int V>
constexpr size_t arr_len(std::array<const size_t, V>){return V;}

template <typename V>
auto make2(V shape) -> Cls<arr_len(shape)>{
  return Cls<arr_len(shape)>();
}
```

I add a runnable MWE here:

https://ideone.com/wrVe9M

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388317/c11-implicit-conversion-from-initialization-list-to-array-parameter) seems to be related but I do not see how it might help. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Look up `std::initializer_list`. Use that instead of `std::array`.

Comment: You could use `std::make_tuple`?

Comment: As for why this doesn't work: how is the compiler to know that `{2, 3}` can ONLY be an `std::array` with length 2? There would have to be a hack specifically for `std::array`.

Comment: Why should `std::initializer_list` help? And why should `std::make_tuple` help? Both are misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can use a variadic `make()` function (`make0()` in the following example) that can calculate the size as `sizeof...(Is)`

The following is a full working example

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>


template<int V>
struct Cls {int val(){return V;} };


template <int V>
auto make(std::array<const size_t, V> shape) -> Cls<V>{
  return Cls<V>();
}

template <typename ... Is>
auto make0 (Is ... is) -> Cls<sizeof...(Is)>
 { return make<sizeof...(Is)>({ {std::size_t(is)... } }); }

int main ()
 {
   auto t1 = make0(2, 3, 5, 7);

   std::cout << t1.val() << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: I was trying to solve it with variadic templates without success. After looking at your solution it seems to be embarrassingly obvious.