# get the size of `std::initializer_list` at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, initializer-list

I am trying to implement the `reshape` function of fortran with C++(11/14) and I designed a function. This function accepts two `std::initializer_list`. The first `initializer_list` gives initial values which I use to initialize a `D`-dimensional array. The second `initializer_list` gives size of each dimension of the array.
I wrote a draft like this

```
template<int D, typename T>
auto forreshape(const std::initializer_list<T> & values, const std::initializer_list<int> & shape)
{
    // some irrelevant codes to calculate lbound
    return for1array_gen<T, D>(lbound, shape, values); // returns D dimension array fornarray<T, D>
}
int main(){
    auto reshaped_array = forreshape<2>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3});
}
```

This implementation requires given non type template parameter `int D`, but I want something without `D`, like `forreshape({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3});`.
At first I want to use `std::initializer_list<T>::size`, however from [static-assert-on-initializer-listsize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438671/static-assert-on-initializer-listsize) I know it doesn't work. Looking around I found [how-to-cause-a-compile-time-error-based-on-the-size-of-an-initializer-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982251/how-to-cause-a-compile-time-error-based-on-the-size-of-an-initializer-list) but it didn't help to my case.
I thought the compiler can get enough infomation and deduce value of `int D` automaticlly, but I don't know how. Maybe its a bad idea to use `std::initializer_list`? I got totally lost here

Comment: `std::initializer_list<>::size()` is `constexpr` in C++14. What's the problem..?

Comment: I use MSVC 2015 and error C2131 occurred when compile,

Comment: MSVC 2015 does not support C++14 `constexpr` (MSVC 2017 does); you'll effectively need a C++11 answer for that compiler.

Comment: @ildjarn: Does C++14 allow `constexpr` parameters?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley : No, but that doesn't mean a level of indirection couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: @ildjarn: I don't know what you mean by that, but I bet it would make a good answer, whatever it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Maybe its a bad idea to use `std::initializer_list`?

I think so. Consider

```
std::initializer_list<int> t;
std::initializer_list<int> a = {1,2,3};
std::initializer_list<int> b = {2,3};
if (rand() > 42)
    t = a;
else
    t = b;
auto reshaped_array = forreshape({1,2,3,4,5,6}, t);
```

In the above example, it's just impossible to know `t.size()` at compile time.

But you can ask the compiler to deduce the length of an initializer list by using a reference to C-style array, thanks to [CWG 1591](http://wg21.link/cwg1591).

The definition of `forreshape` would look like:

```
template<int D, typename T>
auto forreshape(const std::initializer_list<T> & values, const int (&shape)[D])
{
    // use D...
}
```

Comment: Do you have a live example? With me double curly braces where needed then. I would need a C++11 solution actually if that matters (When was that CWG in place?).