# How to `static_assert` the construction of a template class in member initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, static-assert, stdinitializerlist

I have `MyClass` which is a template class. I wanted to provide an initialize r list constructor so that I can conveniently write:

```
MyClass<int> Arr0{ 1,  2,  3, 4, 5, 8 };
```

On the other hand, **I do not want to have duplicates** in this list as this class meant to have only unique user inputs. I have seen many ways to check the duplicates in the array and I came up with the `has_duplicates()` following function.

I tried to combine the idea of checking, whether the `std::initializer_list<T>`ed temporary elements(or array) contains any duplicate elements in the ***member initializer list* itself**; **if it contains `static_assert()` the template instantiation and thereby no object of this class will be constructed.**

Following is the minimal example of my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename Iterator> // function to check duplicates(which works fine)
constexpr bool has_duplicates(Iterator start, Iterator end)
{
    if (start == end) return false;
    using Type = typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*end)>;
    std::map<Type, std::size_t> countMap;
    for (; start != end; ++start)
    {
        countMap[*start]++;
        if (countMap[*start] >= 2) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename T> class MyClass
{
private:
    std::vector<T> m_vec;

public:
    MyClass(std::initializer_list<T> a)
        : (has_duplicates(a.begin(), a.end()) //-----> here is the problem
            ? static_assert(false, " the array has duplicates....")
            : m_vec(a)
           )
    {
        std::cout << "Constriction successful....";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> test{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
        << has_duplicates(test.begin(), test.end()) << std::endl; // works
    MyClass<int> Arr0{ 1,  2,  3, 4 }; // error
    return 0;
}
```

Upon compiling in MSVC 16.0(C++17 flag), this gives me the error:

```
error C2059: syntax error: 'static_assert'
note: while compiling class template member function 'MyClass<int>::MyClass(std::initializer_list<_Ty>)'
      with
      [
          _Ty=int
      ]
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'MyClass<int>::MyClass(std::initializer_list<_Ty>)' being compiled
      with
      [
          _Ty=int
      ]
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MyClass<int>' being compiled
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
error C2059: syntax error: ')'
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

It says an simple syntax error, but I do not see any as per **[static_assert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert).**

**Can anybody help me find out the error?**

**What is the correct way to prevent construction of `std::initializer_list<T>` constutor arguments, in the above case?**

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as a `std::initializer_list<T>` can have values that are only determined at run-time.

Comment: `std::map` isn't a `constexpr` class; so your `has_duplicates()` can't initialize a `constexpr` value

Comment: @cpplearner: Given multiple translation units, it’s not even possible to statically know the *length* of every possible `initializer_list` argument.

Comment: @DavisHerring [Sometimes the length cannot be statically known even when there's only one translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41311112/4672588)

Comment: @cpplearner: I meant you can’t even know the *set* of lengths that might be supplied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do, a **static** assert to check the arguments of a constructor, is (as far I know) simply impossible.

A `static_assert()` works compile time where `MyClass` object is initialized (can be initialized) run-time.

The best I can imagine is a `make_MyClass()` function that receive a list of arguments as template parameters

```
template <auto v0, auto ... vs>
auto make_MyClass ()
 {
   static_assert( false == has_duplicates<v0, vs...>() );

   return MyClass<decltype(v0)>{ v0, vs... };
 }
```

so you can perform a `static_assert()` because now you know compile time the values; I've rewritten the `has_duplicates()` function as follows because your original function can't be effectively `constexpr` (because `std::map` isn't)

```
template <typename = void>
constexpr bool has_duplicates ()
 { return false; }

template <auto v0, auto ... vs>
constexpr bool has_duplicates ()
 { return ((v0 == vs) || ... ) || has_duplicates<vs...>(); }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename = void>
constexpr bool has_duplicates ()
 { return false; }


template <auto v0, auto ... vs>
constexpr bool has_duplicates ()
 { return ((v0 == vs) || ... ) || has_duplicates<vs...>(); }  

template <typename T> class MyClass
{
private:
    std::vector<T> m_vec;

public:
    MyClass(std::initializer_list<T> a) : m_vec{a}
     { std::cout << "Constriction successful...."; }
};

template <auto v0, auto ... vs>
auto make_MyClass ()
 {
   static_assert( false == has_duplicates<v0, vs...>() );

   return MyClass<decltype(v0)>{ v0, vs... };
 }

int main ()
 {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
        << has_duplicates<1, 2, 3, 4, 1>() << std::endl;

    auto mc0 = make_MyClass<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>(); // compile
    //auto mc1 = make_MyClass<1, 2, 3, 4, 1>(); // static_assert error
 }
```

Comment: Damm @max... You are so good at [tag:templates]. I always see your code is too good that I could not follow well ;). But this `((v0 == vs) || ... || has_duplicates<vs...>());` I have. Unfortunately, MSVC gives me the error https://godbolt.org/z/g5OE_s and GCC takes that: https://wandbox.org/permlink/R18zgEqtzmM7w02N. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Const - I suppose MSVC is wrong (but I'm not sure). Anyway I've modified the `has_duplicates()` recursive version to make it happy (but use "/std:c++17" to enable C++17, not "-std-c++17")