# How a function template can deduce the number of times an initializer_list is nested?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stdinitializerlist

I have a function template that takes an arbitrarily nested list and returns an array:

```
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

template<size_t N, typename List>
std::array<size_t,N> some_function (const List& list)
{
    // N is the number of times the list is nested.
    std::array<size_t,N> arr;
    return arr;
}
```

When I use this function for some nested `std::initializer_list`, like this:

```
int main () {
    using List = std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<double>>;
    List list = {{1.,2.,3.},{4.,5.,6.}};

    std::array<size_t,2> arr;
    arr = some_function (list);
    return 0;
}
```

I receive the error that type N can not be deduced

> couldn't deduce template parameter ‘N’

## Question

- How can I improve my function template to deduce the number of times a list is nested?
- Are there better alternatives than `std::initializer_list` for this case?

Comment: What do you expect `arr` to be after `arr = some_function (list);`. `N` in `std::array` is the size of the array.

Comment: Also, you are using a `std::array` with the value type `std::size_t`, but your list holds doubles. Please clarify your question.

Comment: As far as I understand the assignment `arr = some_function (list)` isn't used in type deduction. So only `some_function (list)` is used. But then there isn't a way for compiler to know the size of array.

Comment: The size of an initializer_list is not known at compile time.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311023/get-the-size-of-stdinitializer-list-at-compile-time

Comment: are you trying to get `{ 2, 3 }` from `{{1.,2.,3.},{4.,5.,6.}}`? I.e. the size of each dimension?

Comment: @super Thanks. Just to clarify the type of 'std::array' has nothing to do with type of the input List.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks. This makes sense.

Comment: @Caleth Not exactly this but something like that. I simplified the function, so it may look strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write two overloaded `constexpr` [function templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) to calculate the nested times, with the help of [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

```
// types have not member type value_type
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_value_type: std::false_type {};
// types have member type value_type
template <typename T>
struct has_value_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type>> : std::true_type {};

// return nested times as 0 for types without member type value_type
template<typename T>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<!has_value_type<T>::value, size_t> get_nested_times() {
    return 0;
}
// return nested times as 1 plus times got on the nested type recursively
template<typename T>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<has_value_type<T>::value, size_t> get_nested_times() {
    return 1 + get_nested_times<typename T::value_type>();
}
```

then you can get the nested times at compile-time as

```
template<typename List>
auto some_function (const List& list)
{
    // N is the number of times the list is nested.
    constexpr auto N = get_nested_times<List>();
    std::array<size_t, N> arr;
    return arr;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jGm5y3nNZRFHxMeC)

Comment: Thanks, this is a very nice solution. However, I think it is still necessary to call the function explicitly as `some_function<get_nested_times<List>(),List> ` , because the type deduction will fail otherwise.

Comment: @Ali If you can change the function signature as I showed then you don't have to do that. You can get `N` inside the `some_function` instead of specifying it as template parameter.

Comment: Notice that your example will work with C++17 as well as the C++20 you compiled it with in the live demo.

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes, you are right. I forgot to update the definition of function template.