# C++11 - static_assert within constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert, constexpr

How would one properly do a `static_assert` within a `constexpr` function?  For example:

```
constexpr int do_something(int x)
{
  static_assert(x > 0, "x must be > 0");
  return x + 5;
}
```

This is not valid C++11 code, because a constexpr function must only contain a return statement.  I don't think that the standard has an exception to this, although, the GCC 4.7 does not let me compile this code.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> This is not valid C++11 code, because a constexpr function must only contain a return statement.

This is incorrect. `static_assert` in a `constexpr` function are fine. What is *not* fine is using function parameters in constant expressions, like you do it.

You could throw if `x <= 0`. Calling the function in a context that requires a constant expression will then fail to compile

```
constexpr int do_something(int x) {
  return x > 0 ? (x + 5) : (throw std::logic_error("x must be > 0"));
}
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know `throw`s in a `constexpr` function that is called in a constexpr context will cause the compilation to fail!

Comment: @Xeo doing *anything* non-constexpressy on the other side of ?: will do the job. :)

Comment: Nice complement to `static_assert` I must say. :)

Comment: I'm confused why "using function parameters in constant expressions" is "not fine". If 'x' is a constant expression then (x+5) is also a constant expression and can be evaluated at compile-time. If 'x' isn't a constant expression then the function itself loses its constexpr-ness (for that particular invocation) and will simply be evaluated at run-time. Could someone clarify?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb does an alternative exist which does not use throw? In particular for library code, one must think that their clients might want to compile their programs with exceptions turned off. In this case this fails with gcc-4.8 even if the throw case never happens.

Comment: @monkey_05_06: Because 'x' is a function argument and therefore **not** a constexpr. Remember, a constexpr function must also be suitable as a runtime function (with non-constexpr args), and thus its args are ineligible for use in a static_assert(...) declaration. This is regardless of whether you ever actually call the function from a non-constexpr context, which is why the requirement that a constexpr function must also be runtime-callable is as much of a restriction as it is a "feature".

Comment: @gnzlbg: See his comment above about using anything that isn't a `constexpr`. What I did (as a generic solution) was declare a **non-**constexpr function template like so... `template<typename RT> RT non_constexpr() { return RT{}; }` ...to use like this... `return (x > 0) ? (x + 5) : non_constexpr<int>();` ... tested in g++ and clang++.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Can you give an example? I can't use exceptions (writing for a microcontroller so they are disabled).

Comment: Actually this is not that great as it only works when the result is a constexpr. E.g. `const int foo = do_something(-1);` still compiles (which is weird because I would have thought it ran the constexpr code in that case?)

Comment: @Timmmm No, the function is only evaluated as `constexpr` if it is called in a `constexpr` context, which of course, initialising/assigning to a non-`constexpr` object is no such context. When declaring an object, `constexpr` implies `const` but **not** the other way around. But _cppist_'s answer might work for you, i.e. if you want the arguments always to be `constexpr`, then make them _template_ arguments, not function arguments.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That is very cool! But I don't get it why throw in a constexpr function that is called in a constexpr context will cause the compilation to fail. Is it the behavior defined in c++ standard?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb  I test it with if (x<=0) throw "error";  it will report error in compile time either. Is that means when x>0, throw "error" will not be compiled ?

Answer (score 24):

This works and is valid C++11 code, because template arguments are compile time only:

```
template <int x>
constexpr int do_something() {
    static_assert(x > 0, "x must be > 0");
    return x + 5;
}
```

I faced with the same problems as you did with constant expressions in C++. There's few clear documentation about constexprs at the moment. And note that there's some known bugs with it in gcc's issue tracker, but your problem seems not to be a bug.

Note that if you declare constexpr functions inside classes, you are not able to use them inside the class. This also seems to be not a bug.

Edit: This is allowed according to the standard: 7.1.3 states

... or a compound-statement that contains only

- null statements,
- **static_assert**-declarations
- typedef declarations and alias-declarations that do not
   define classes or enumerations,
- using-declarations,
- using-directives,
- and exactly one return statement

Comment: No. constexpr must be only a single return statement.

Comment: I read the standard. You are correct, this is fine. I edited your answer to add that.

Comment: Thank you. This way works for me very well. I can not use exceptions, because they are disabled in my build (small embedded system).

Comment: How do you call this function?

Comment: @marsh: `do_something<x>();` -which means x must be a compile-time value.