# How to tell static_assert that constexpr function arguments are const?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have a constexpr function that looks something like this:

```
constexpr int foo(int bar)
{
   static_assert(bar>arbitrary_number, "Use a lower number please");

   return something_const;
}
```

However, compiling this with GCC 4.6.3 keeps telling me

error: 'bar' cannot appear in a constant-expression

I tried something like

```
constexpr int foo(constexpr const int bar)
{
   static_assert(bar>arbitrary_number, "Use a lower number please");

   return something_const;
}
```

but constexpr can't be used for function arguments.

Is there some simple way to tell the compiler that bar is always a compile time constant?

Comment: Oops, totally forgot to codify that part. Thanks @Henrik

Comment: A constexpr function can be called with non-const arguments, it simply forfeits its constexpr'ness.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++11 - static_assert within constexpr function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626055/c11-static-assert-within-constexpr-function)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there some simple way to tell the compiler that bar is always a compile time constant?

If `bar` is always compile-time constant, then you should write your function as:

```
template<int bar>
constexpr int foo()
{
   static_assert(bar>arbitrary_number, "Use a lower number please");
   return something_const;
}
```

Because if you don't do so, and instead write what you've already written, then in that case, the function *can be* called with *non-const* argument as well; it is just that when you pass non-const argument, then the function will loss it's *constexpr*-ness.

Note that in the above code `arbitrary_number` should be constant expression as well, or else it will not compile.

Comment: what type of syntax is `template<int bar>`? a full template specialization like `template <> ...`?

Answer (score 5):

`constexpr` functions *may* be evaluated at compile time, it's not forced by the standard in general (you can force the function to be evaluated at compile time by using it inside a constant expression like initializing a `constexpr` variable with it).

Also, the arguments of a `constexpr` function are in fact not constant, they may change with every call (even if evaluated at compile time).

One work around is to use a non-type template to pass `bar`, if it's always a compile time constant (which it seems to be).

Answer (score 0):

`foo` can be used in the following manner:

```
int i;
std::cin >> i;
foo("foo", i);
```

As you can see `i` isn't exactly a constant expression above, yet it can still be used with a `constexpr` functions. `constexpr` functions (and function templates) are a strange beast that guarantee that e.g. `foo(p, i)` is a constant expression iff `p` and `i` also are, *but* can still be used like regular functions.

If arguments to your functions are truly meant to always be constant expressions, then they should be template arguments, not function arguments.