# How can I force a constexpr function to be constant evaluated?

Tags: c++, macros, c++17, constexpr, compile-time

I recently wrote some code which prints a function result to `cout`. The result could have been evaluated at compile time, but it wasn't:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

constexpr unsigned int gcd(unsigned int u, unsigned int v)
{
    // ...
}

int main() {
    std::cout << gcd(5, 3) << std::endl;
}
```

For whatever bizarre reason, this compiles to: (`clang -O3 -std=c++17`)

```
main:
    push    r14
    push    rbx
    push    rax
    mov     edi, 5
    mov     esi, 3
    call    gcd(unsigned int, unsigned int)
    mov     esi, eax
    ...
```

See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rc9x78) for a live example.

I would like the compiler to evaluate `gcd(5, 3)` at compile time in order to avoid wasting cycles at runtime, which is obviously possible. I know that I could do the following:

```cpp
int main() {
    constexpr unsigned g = gcd(5, 3); 
    std::cout << g << std::endl;
}
```

However, this is unnecessarily verbose. What I would like to do is simply this:

```cpp
#define CONSTEVAL(expression) // ...

int main() {
    std::cout << CONSTEVAL(gcd(5, 3)) << std::endl;
}
```

Does there exist any kind of compiler builtin that would make this `CONSTEVAL` macro possible? Or even better - something fully portable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about an immediately invoked lambda expression?

```
#define CONSTEVAL(...) []{ constexpr auto result = __VA_ARGS__; return result; }()
```

This is effectively a way to produce a `constexpr` variable to hold the result and evaluate to the variable's value.

---

This can also be done macro-less via a template, but only if the value can be passed as a template parameter:

```
template <auto V>
inline constexpr auto consteval_v = V;
```

Used as `consteval_v<gcd(5, 3)>`.

Comment: Nice. Does this have to be a macro though?

Comment: That works. Why use `__VA_ARGS__` though? To preserve commas or what?

Comment: @J.Schultke Exactly. As an example, `CONSTEVAL(some_template_function<5, 3>(1))` wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: @cigien In fact, it does not. If the constexpr value can be passed as a template parameter, we can use a template. However, that is less general, as not every constexpr value can be passed as a template parameter (e.g. I think floats are an exception)