# C++ constexpr function always evaluated at compile time?

Tags: c++, constexpr

If I want to have a function that behaves the same as a macro, that is, compute the value at compile time, can I use a constexpr function?

For example, can I replace the Foo macro by the foo function and still have a compile time evaluated result in all of the following cases:

```cpp
#define FOO(x) (x + 2)

constexpr int foo(int x) {
    return x + 2;
}

void doSomething(int a) { ... }

int main() {
    int res1 = foo(3);
    doSomething(foo(4));
    const int res2 = foo(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does a constexpr function get evaluated at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248235/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time)

Comment: This can also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63637443/1896169

Answer (score 4):

With C++20, [consteval](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) might be your friend here:

```
consteval int foo(int x) {
    return x + 2;
}

int main() {
    constexpr int r = foo(2);
}
```

Comment: Is `constexpr` required in `constexpr int r = foo(2);`? If so, what's the point of using `consteval` instead of `constexpr` when defining `foo`? (I think the result would be the same if consteval is changed to constexpr in your example.)

Answer (score 3):

By themselves, `constexpr` functions are not required to be evaluated at compile time. However, you can force them to be evaluated by assigning the return value to a constexpr variable:

```cpp
doSomething(foo(4)); // foo(4) not guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time
constexpr auto result = foo(4); // foo(4) _is_ guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time
doSomething(result):
```

Also, a note about your question on macros. A macro definition has nothing to do with compile time evaluation. It's more akin to an always inline function.

Comment: Actually, the first one is guaranteed to be evaluated at run-time.

Comment: @cigien Is it somehow exempt from the as-if rule?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, the program must still behave *as-if* the call was constant evaluated. I'll try and write an answer.

Comment: @cigien - Do you mean the `foo()` call in `doSomething(foo(4))`? Are you sure?

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to detect if something was evaluated at runtime or compile-time using only the C++ itself, so the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) allows the compiler to do whatever it wants.

Nothing stops a compiler from performing the addition in your macro at runtime, and nothing stops it from calculating even a non-`constexpr` function at compile-time (as long as it doesn't perform any IO, etc). It all depends on optimization settings and the sanity of the compiler.

Normally, in unoptimized builds, `constexpr` functions are executed at runtime unless the return value is used in a context that requires a compile-time constant. This includes initializing a `constexpr` variable from it, and your `const int res2` implicitly becomes `constexpr` because its initializer is `constexpr`, so `foo(5)` should be called at compile-time.

In optimized builds, you can expect the compiler to do as much as possible at compile-time. (A function doesn't even have `constexpr`, as long as the function body is visible in the current translation unit, or if link-time optimizations are enabled.)