# Using constexpr for both runtime and compile-time evaluations - passing constexpr value as a function parameter

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, constexpr-function

I'm trying to make a constexpr function which will run both at compile and runtime depending on the call.The function will check a  unsigned long and will return a number depending on it's value. Parameter can be either known at compile time or a variable that's why I cannot use consteval.

```
constexpr std::uint32_t GetFlagFromFlagName(unsigned long FlagName)
{

    if (!std::is_constant_evaluated())
    {
        std::cout << "Running function at runtime" << '\n';
    }


    switch (FlagName)
    {
    case 0:
        return 10;
    case 1:
        return 20;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}


void MyTestFunc(std::uint32_t test)
{
    std::cout << "test>>>" << test << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto CompileTimeVariable = GetFlagFromFlagName(0); // Should be Compile-time
    std::cout << "CompileTimeVariable result>>>" << CompileTimeVariable << "\n";

    MyTestFunc(GetFlagFromFlagName(0)); // Not compile time

    system("pause");
}
```

result is:

```
CompileTimeVariable result>>>10 
Running function at runtime 
test>>>10
```

Expected output:( std::cout << "Running function at runtime" << '\n'; never runs)

```
CompileTimeVariable result>>>10 
test>>>10
```

Second call of GetFlagFromFlagName is evaluated at runtime but I expect it to be evaluated at compile-time becaused I passed it a compile-time variable 0.

I understand that in order to make a variable evaluate at at compile time I should make it constexpr. Is there a way to pass result of GetFlagFromFlagName without declaring it a separate variable before?Casting a function result to constexpr doesn't work:

```
MyTestFunc((constexpr)GetFlagFromFlagName(0));
```

Comment: is the code not working as intended?

Comment: Yes because I expect GetFlagFromFlagName to evaluate at compile-time when I'm calling it with MyTestFunc because I passed it a compile-time variiable 0. But according to the console output it's evaluated at run-time.(I've edited the question, thank you.)

Comment: You should also add all the needed `#include`s.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Added expected output for clarity, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand when something is evaluated as a constant expression. `GetFlagFromName(0)` receives `0` as an argument, which is a constant expression, and could be constant-evaluated.

However constant evaluation doesn't take place whenever possible, or whenever the compiler feels like it.
It only takes place in specific contexts, such as

- array sizes
- template arguments
- initializers of `constexpr` variables
- ...

See also [When does a constexpr function get evaluated at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14248235/5740428)

If you want to force constant-evaluation of `GetFlagFromName`, see [single expression helper for compile-time enforced constexpr function evaluation possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14309245/5740428). You would write something like:

```cpp
MyTestFunc(CONSTEVAL(GetFlagFromFlagName(0)));
```

If `GetFlagFromName` is *never* evaluated at run-time, you could also just make it `consteval` which forces constant evaluation in every context.
However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Last but not least, if the `FlagName` parameter is always meant to be a constant expression, you could turn it into a template parameter:

```cpp
template <unsigned long FlagName>
constexpr std::uint32_t GetFlagFromFlagName()
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm marking it as an answer. However the CONSTEVAL macro from the link doesn't compile. I used this one instead #define CONSTEVAL(...) []() consteval { return __VA_ARGS__; }()

Comment: @NormakLOE32 Perhaps you didn't use `-std=c++20` or you're using an old compiler that doesn't support `consteval` functions/lambdas yet or something. It should work in principle.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (v143) and ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20), not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: You could post a separate question with those details and the error message then.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **`consteval` lambda** as shown below:

```
MyTestFunc([]() consteval { return GetFlagFromFlagName(0); }());
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sG8xK3Mcr)