# C++11 - bad_alloc on a constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Arrays with bitmasks are really popular, often times they are tedious to write and they make the code less readable, I would like to generate them with a `constexpr`, here is my try

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

typedef uint32_t myT;

template <typename T>
constexpr std::vector<T> vecFarm(T &&lower, T &&upper, T &&step) {
  // std::cout << lower << " " << upper << " " << step << "\n";
  std::vector<T> v;
  if (lower < upper) {
    for (T count = lower; count < upper; count += step) {
      v.push_back(count);
    };
  }
  return (v);
}

int main() {

  std::vector<myT> k(std::move(vecFarm(myT(0), ~(myT(0)), myT(256)))); //why
  // this doesn't work ?
  // std::vector<myT> k(std::move(vecFarm(myT(0), ((~(myT(0))) >> 16), myT(256))));
  // but this one works
  // let's see what we got
  for (const auto &j : k) {
    std::cout << j << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";

  return (0);
}
```

I have used `std::move`, unnamed objects and a `constexpr`, this code compiles fine with

```
g++-4.8 -O3 -std=c++11 -pthread -Werror -Wall -Wextra
```

but it fails at runtime because of a `bad_alloc`, and I can see my "small" application allocating a lot of space .

Maybe the error is huge and I can't see it, but why this doesn't work ?

Why my application does the allocation at run-time ? Isn't supposed to compute everything at compile-time ? I was expecting this to maybe fail at compile-time not at run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::bad_alloc` usually means it cannot allocate any more memory. Changing your code to the following will show you why:

```
for (T count = lower; count < upper; count += step) {
    std::cout << "count:" << count << "\n";
    std::cout << "upper:" << upper << "\n";
};
```

This prints the following on the first loop when I tested it:

```
count:0
upper:4294967295
```

In other words, you have a long way to go before `count < upper` fails and the for loop stops, especially since you are adding only `256` each time.

Also, in order for `constexpr` functions to be evaluated at compile time, there are certain [conditions it has to fullfil](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr). For example, `its return type must be LiteralType`, and your function returns `std::vector`, also, `exactly one return statement that contains only literal values, constexpr variables and functions.` and you have a compound statement. Therefore, your function cannot be evaluated at compile time.

Also, note that if you do not fullfill these conditions, the `constexpr` qualifier is ignored, although if you turn on `-pedantic` it should give you better diagnostics.

Comment: It may be worth noting that if he makes the function non-template, his code won't compile at all.

Comment: Infact I was focusing on the range for my type `uint32_t` and I forgot that a vector needs memory too ... ; so if I would like to break the compilation if the `constexpr` qualifier is ignored what is the best way to do just that ?

Comment: @user2485710: [It's not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309245/single-expression-helper-for-compile-time-enforced-constexpr-function-evaluation).

Comment: @JesseGood neither type_traits or assertions ? Nothing of nothing ?

Comment: @user2485710: There are a few [tricks shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294271/forcing-a-constant-expression-to-be-evaluated-during-compile-time?lq=1), if you try to use the function where a constant expression is required, it will of course fail, but nothing in general is possible (although I think there is a C++ proposal to change this).