# Compile-time evaluation of constexpr functions

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider **the only cases** in which it is possible for the compiler to evaluate a `constexpr`  function at compile-time. In these cases, it's not clear from the standard (paragraph 5.19) whether it is always **mandatory** for the compiler to evaluate `constexpr` functions at compile-time or not; if it is not always mandatory, I would eventually like to see some examples where the standard does give strong guarantees about compile-time evaluations of constexpr functions.

```
constexpr int f(int n) {
   return n*n;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's mandatory when the `constexpr` function is valid to be evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: It will work at compile time for `f(2)` but not likely for `cin >> x; f(x);`.

Comment: [When does a constexpr function get evaluated at compile time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248235/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks BO, I think the "When does a constexpr function get evaluated at compile time?" answered question better answers to my question too, the other one being not really clear in one case.