# c++11 user defined literals, conflicts with compilation/execution dichotomy

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

I know the ISO C standard make a big deal about separating translation behaviour and execution behaviour, partly to ensure cross-compilers don't have to carry the execution environment of every target.

By that, I mean the compiler has limited information available to it compared to a running program. That limits what you can do in the source code, such as not initialising a variable based on the return value from a function like this:

```
int twice (int val) { return val * 2; }
int xyzzy = twice (7);
int main () { printf ("%d\n", xyzzy); return 0; }
```

What I'm curious about is how user defined literals in C++11 fit into this scheme. Since the literal evaluation relies on a function, what's to stop that function doing things like:

- returning a random value (even if based on the input such as `42_roughly` giving you a value between 40 and 44)?
- having side effects, such as changing global variables?

Does the fact that a function have to be called means that these *aren't* really literals in the sense of being calculated at compile time?

If that's the case, what's the advantage of these literals over any other function call. In other words why is:

```
int xyzzy = 1101_1110_b;
```

preferable to:

```
int xyzzy = makeBin ("1101_1110");
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The secret is all in whether you declare the user-defined literal functions as `constexpr` or not.

Compare this (normal execution-time function):

```
#include <iostream>
int operator "" _twice(unsigned long long num) { return num*2; }
int xyzzy = 7_twice;
int main () { std::cout << xyzzy << "\n"; return 0; }
```

With this (compile-time constant, the `static_assert` works):

```
#include <iostream>
constexpr int operator "" _twice(unsigned long long num) { return num*2; }
int xyzzy = 7_twice;
int main () {
    static_assert(7_twice == 14, "not compile time constant");
    std::cout << xyzzy << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, declaring a function `constexpr` restricts all statements within to be `constexpr` also, or compile-time constants; no random number shenanigans allowed.

Comment: So, presumably, if you declare it `constexpr`, it can be evaluated at compile time completely (though I gather this may cause issues when cross-compiling to an environment with different rules - a cross compiler would need to carry many execution environs or defer calculation to runtime). Without `constexpr`, it may have to defer the calculation anyway. I'll make sure I use `constexpr` :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm not aware that cross-compiling would affect `constexpr`; however from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14248310/2038264) it appears that to guarantee compile-time evaluation of a `constexpr`, its arguments must be `constexpr` also.

Comment: @paxdiablo: `constexpr` expressions are severly restricted, to the point where cross-compilers must be able to evaluate them. Cross-compilers have always been able to evaluate quite complex expressions: `int foo[(7/3==3)?4:(5>2?Bar<6>::baz:2]` must be all evaluated at compile time. What `constexpr` primarily adds is the ability to _name_ certain expressions.