# Compile-time evaluation of constexpr functions in debug mode

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, metaprogramming, constexpr

I have been playing with the following code snippet to understand `constexpr`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

///////////////////
bool runtimeIsPalindrome(const char* s, int len)
{
  if(len < 2)
    return true;
  else
    return s[0] == s[len-1] && runtimeIsPalindrome(&s[1], len-2);
}

///////////////////
constexpr bool compileTimeIsPalindrome(const char* s, int len)
{
    return len < 2 ? true : s[0] == s[len-1] && compileTimeIsPalindrome(&s[1], len-2);
}

///////////////////
int main()
{
    constexpr char c[] = "helloworlddlrowolleh";
    for(size_t nn=0;nn<1e8; ++nn) {
        // static_assert(compileTimeIsPalindrome(c, sizeof(c)-1 ), "Blah");
        // compileTimeIsPalindrome(c, sizeof(c)-1 );
        // runtimeIsPalindrome( c, sizeof(c)-1 );
    }
}
```

With the `runtimeIsPalindrome` version ...

```
clear; g++ -std=c++11 plaindrome.cpp; time ./a.out 
real    0m8.333s
user    0m8.322s
sys     0m0.005s
```

With the `compileTimeIsPalindrome` version ...

```
clear; g++ -std=c++11 plaindrome.cpp; time ./a.out
real    0m8.257s
user    0m8.247s
sys     0m0.004s
```

... but with the `static_assert(compileTimeIsPalindrome` version I actually appear to observe some compile time magic ...

```
clear; g++ -std=c++11 plaindrome.cpp; time ./a.out
real    0m0.265s
user    0m0.263s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Why does compile-time evaluation only work when I try the assertion in this example?

Note: Profiling with any optimisation seems pointless for this example, as it appears the compiler spots that the result is constant irrespective of the function called in the loop  giving similar timings to the fastest profile time above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`constexpr` doesn't guarantee compile time evaluation, unless used in a `static_assert`, template argument or any other place where the value has to be known at compile time by the language rules.

The fibonacci series `f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2), f(0) = f(1) = 1` is a great example for that. On my machine with gcc, for `n <= 10`, this get's evaluated at compile time. For any other argument, the compiler is allowed to -- and indeed does -- decide that it is too computationally intensive and default to runtime evaluation.

Comment: Ah, I missed the key point of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248235/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time/14248310#14248310  ". . . and the result is used in a constant expression as well"