# constexpr doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 + CTP.

I have defined the following function:

```
constexpr DWORD const_getHash(const char *str, DWORD curHash = 0) {
    return !*str ? curHash : const_getHash(str + 1, 
        (curHash >> 13 | curHash << (32 - 13)) + (*str >= 'a' ? *str - 32 : *str));
}
```

which I use like this:

```
DWORD hash = const_getHash("ok");
```

The compiler doesn't issue any warnings but by looking at the "disassembly" I can tell that const_getHash() is executed at runtime.

What's wrong?

edit: If I force the function to be executed at compile-time with

```
constexpr DWORD hash = const_getHash("ok");
```

the compiler says

```
Error   1   error C2127: 'hash': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression
```

Comment: It's probably some limitation of the VS compiler, since it works on [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7355eb8392a93539)

Comment: @TomKnapen Damn! I might turn to GCC then. I can't compute the hashes at runtime because I'm writing a shellcode which needs to be as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

`constexpr` doesn't force the function to be executed at compile-time. It just tells the compiler that the function ***can*** be executed at compile-time ***if*** needed.

> `constexpr` functions will be evaluated at compile time when all its arguments are constant expressions and the result is used in a constant expression as well.

(Quoted from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248235/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time).)