# How to determine if a constexpr class is built at compile time or not?

Tags: c++11, constexpr

Let's consider the following code:

```
class A {
public:
   constexpr A(int value) : m_value(value);
private:
   const int m_value;
};

void f(const A& a);

f(42); // OK
f(std::rand()); // KO - How to detect this case?
```

Is there a way to determine if A is built at compile time or run-time?

Comment: Admittedly, I don't use C++ a whole lot, so please correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the whole point of `constexpr` to guarantee that the expression is indeed built at compile-time?

Comment: No, constexpr indicates that it should if it possible. This is just an indication actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248235/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time

Comment: It seems to me that the answer to the question you linked rather confirms my statement: "*`constexpr` functions* will *be evaluated at compile time when all its arguments are constant expressions and the result is used in a constant expression as well.*"

Comment: f(42) will be constructed at compile time, f(std::rand()) will not :)

Comment: Indeed, since its arguments aren't `constexpr`s, in accordance with the quote.

Comment: Indeed, I rephrased my question. I want to be able to warn the user that they are using the API in a sub-optimal way somehow.

Comment: There is no way to disallow runtime usage of a constexpr function such as `A::A(int)`. For this we need constexpr function parameters which do not exist in C++11/14, i.e. `A::A(constexpr int)` (not legal C++ as of now).

Comment: I would like to rely on overloading, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3583.pdf (9.4 Forbidding Runtime Execution with Overloading) but I cannot come up with an example that compiles...

Answer (score 0):

One way to *verify* that an expression is indeed a `constexpr` is to assign it to a `constexpr` variable:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int a = f(42);
    constexpr int b = f(std::rand());
    return(0);
}
```

Since the value `constexpr` variables must be computable by the compiler, the assignment of `b` will produce an error. GCC says the following:

```
foo.cpp:25:35: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘int rand()’
     constexpr int b = f(std::rand());
```

I'm not sure if it can be done in a way to merely produce a warning, however.