# Why can not I use constexpr value in function, but I can do the same in scope of this value?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr, compile-time

I can't use constexpr value in function, as opposed to outside of the function.

- I can use `auto ar1 = std::array<int, il.size()>();` in scope where `il` is defined.
- But I can't use `{ return std::array<T, il.size()>();}` in `constexpr`-function `il_to_array()`

Why can not I use constexpr value in function, but I can do the same in block scope of this value?

http://ideone.com/5g0iRE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <array>

constexpr size_t size_to_size(size_t v) { return v; }   // 1 - OK

template<typename T>
constexpr size_t il_to_size(std::initializer_list<T> il) { return il.size(); }  // 2 - OK

// 3 - error
template<typename T>
constexpr auto il_to_array(std::initializer_list<T> il) {return std::array<T, il.size()>();}

template<size_t N>
void print_constexpr() { std::cout << N << std::endl; }

int main() {

    constexpr std::initializer_list<int> il = { 1, 2, 3 };
    print_constexpr<il.size()>();   // 0 - OK

    print_constexpr< size_to_size(il.size()) >();   // 1 - OK

    print_constexpr< il_to_size(il) >();    // 2 - OK

    auto ar1 = std::array<int, il.size()>();    // OK - body of function: il_to_array()

    //auto ar2 = il_to_array(il);   // 3 - error

    return 0;
}
```

For example, there we see, that template-constexpr-function will not fail, even if it may be or may not be `constexpr` - depends of T, because one of instance may be `constexpr`: [Why does the C++ compiler makes it possible to declare a function as constexpr, which can not be constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850730/why-does-the-c-compiler-makes-it-possible-to-declare-a-function-as-constexpr)

- And it can be concluded that if this is a template-function, it may be specialization any of: `constexpr` and non-`constexpr`.
- And on the basis of [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) - if we use only `constexpr`-arguments then instantiates only `constexpr`-instance, and it does not matter that non-`constexpr`-function could not be instantiated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The arguments of (constexpr) functions are not `constexpr`.

`constexpr` functions might be given arguments which were not known at compile time.

So following is valid whether `v` is known at compile time or not

```
constexpr size_t size_to_size(size_t v) { return v; }
```

But following function doesn't work as `il` is not `constexpr` and non type template parameter requires to be known at compile time:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto il_to_array(std::initializer_list<T> il) {return std::array<T, il.size()>();}
```

This is true even if the function is only called with arguments known at compile time.

Comment: Err... I am not sure the story ends here for the OP's woes... [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5440da7ff6a1316) and [MSVC](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) fails to compile the OP's code (only gcc does). They reject it because they do not consider the creation of `std::initializer_list<int>` a `constexpr`.. Which I believe: because the standard isn't clear about it being `constexpr` except for it's member functions. Another supporting logic, what if `T` isn't initializable as a `constexpr` in `std::initializer_list<T>`?

Comment: @WhiZTiM: Look at [why-isnt-stdinitializer-list-defined-as-a-literal-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496004/why-isnt-stdinitializer-list-defined-as-a-literal-type?noredirect=1&lq=1) for that error.

Comment: I went through the links all up to the [forum discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/aA3BsR4ZuoE/discussion) .. And according to Richard Smith's response, Clang and MSVC are correct about `constexpr std::initializer_list<int> il = {1,2,3,4};` being ill-formed.