# Can I get a function table inlined?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, inline

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

inline void f()
{
    std :: cout << "Welcome to f!" << std :: endl;
}

inline void g()
{
    std :: cout << "Welcome to g!" << std :: endl;
}

inline void h()
{
    std :: cout << "Welcome to h!" << std :: endl;
}

typedef void (*function)();
const function table[] = {f, g, h};

int main()
{
    int idx;
    std :: cin >> idx;
    table[idx]();
}
```

Here I have three functions, `f`, `g` and `h`. I put their pointers into a `const` array. Then, at runtime, I ask my user to provide a number and the corresponding function in the table is called.

I guess this is not going to get inlined, am I correct? I tried to inspect the assembly code but I really suck at reading assembly.

So I wonder, do I have better options to get the call to either `f`, `g` and `h` inlined? I mean, if I were to just make a switch this would work flawlessly.

Note: this is just an example, in a real-world scenario I will have a set of functions, known at compile time but determined by a kinda lengthy procedure. So I am not able to just, e.g., write the code in a switch statement.

Comment: The standard doesn't say much about optimizations. Most optimizations rely on the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) and are not standarized. Not only does it greatly depend on which compiler you are using and the flags you use, but small changes to the code may change when and where optimizations are applied. So a small example may not be representative of a larger project. The best bet would be to try it for your use case and check it yourself. If your case is relatively simple, you can try https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: If the function gets called only after a "kinda lengthy procedure", why worry about inlining at all?

Comment: "I guess this is not going to get inlined", probably not. remember inline is just an hint...

Comment: `table[idx]();` if `idx` is given at runtime, how could the compiler determine if there's a `inline` function selected or not? I'm also not sure if a `switch` selection might help to optimize, since the table still can contain functions that aren't hinted to be inlined.

Comment: @Lanting I didn't explain myself, sorry: there is a lengthy compile-time procedure (e.g. complicated recursions of templates) that in the end determine a set of functions in that form. The lengthy procedure is completely done at compile time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that does make a lot of sense. What I mean when I say that a `switch` would be more optimized is: if I copied the bodies of `f`, `g` and `h` in a `switch` statement, this would be more efficient than fetching from a table in that form. Am I correct?

Comment: @MatteoMonti _"Am I correct?"_ Yes you are. I had something else in mind (using a `switch` + the table).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ see, that's what bugs me: you cannot make some kind of `template switch`, where the `case`s of the switch are determined by a template. The best approximation you can get with templates and recursion is a chain if `if`s. What I was trying to do here is the equivalent of a jumptable, which makes a `switch` faster than a chain of `if`s..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  "_Am I correct?_" (in thinking a switch being more efficient). Unless your functions involve horrendous parameter passing, or are on an extremely critical code-path and are exceedingly lightweight, then I would have thought the (very small) difference in overhead between a function call and jumping into and out of the correct bit of the switch statement would be insignificant compared executing the selected code.

Comment: @TripeHound Well, that's true for all these kind of _micro optimization_ attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you make use of proper const expressions, it is guaranteed that the code will be inlined at compile time. Have a look at the conditionals for that in this thread: [When does a constexpr function get evaluated at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248235/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time)