# c++20 and float endianness

Tags: c++, floating-point, endianness, c++20

Short:

- Does the c++20 endian proposal only deal with integer types, or does it also give information on float types?
- Will it add useful standard library functions for dealing with endianness?

---

Dealing with serialization correctly across platforms is difficult, and the weird possibilities of float endianness are even more frustrating (curses to whoever decided ARM middle-endian floats were a good idea). Unfortunately the articles I could find online discussing c++20 features mention integer types but not floats.

Did the standards committee overlook float and double types?
Please tell me no.

Also, the articles I could find seemed to suggest the additions will only provide a way to detect endianness, but not provide standard library functions for converting between different encodings. If that was the case, this doesn't seem any more useful than just standardizing a preprocessor definition.

Can someone knowledgeable about the upcoming c++20 proposals lay out what is (and is not) being included in the new endian features? (... and the 'why' would be awesome if you happen to know)

Comment: "*this doesn't seem any more useful than just standardizing a preprocessor definition.*" But it isn't; it's an enumeration. Which means that it is a `constexpr` value, unlike a preprocessor definition which is just a macro.

Comment: instead of looking at articles, here are some links to standards papers themselves [original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0463r1.html), and [update](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1612r0.pdf). Supporting library call: byteswap ([link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1272r0.html))

Comment: this mentioned byteswap [standards_meeting_summary](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/au0c4x/201902_kona_iso_c_committee_trip_report_c20/), but it appears to not have made it in [later_meeting_summary](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/cfk9de/201907_cologne_iso_c_committee_trip_report_the/) No mention of byteswap and comment said byteswap didn't make it. Unfortunately it doesn't mention endian either, so are we sure that made it in?

Comment: [Yes, we're sure](http://eel.is/c++draft/bit.endian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the c++20 endian proposal only deal with integer types, or does it also give information on float types?

As it stands, it'll tell you if *all* scalar types are big or little endian - or, the horror, they are not and you're dealing with *mixed* endianess.

All arithmetic types are included in [scalars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_scalar), both integer and floating point types.

The why: Pure speculation, but making a portable test when having seen gazillions of C type punning versions ported to C++ would be one *why*.

> Also, the articles I could find seemed to suggest the additions will only provide a way to detect endianness, but not provide standard library functions for converting between different encodings. If that was the case, this doesn't seem any more useful than just standardizing a preprocessor definition.

You only get a portable way to detect endianess.

Comment: So on an ARM system with little endian integers, I will not be able to tell the endianess of the integers if the floats happen to not be little endian? Or are you saying I can ask for all scalar types if that type is little, big, or neither?

Comment: @PorkWonton You will get a mixed result as I made an example of here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53503457/7582247

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Ugh, this makes the proposal worse than just standardizing something equivalent of gcc's `__BYTE_ORDER__` and `__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__` preprocessor definitions.

Comment: @PorkWonton It's one step closer to good :-) It'll also be in C++20 that integers use two's complement. The fact that it's not already standardized has caused _a few_ bugs over the years to say the least.  It's perhaps decisions like that that can't be enforced until the last one's complement computer has gone offline. I'm hoping that the endian part we got this time will be accompanied with other goodies in C++13.