# Is it possible in C++ to use the same code with and without compile time constants?

Tags: c++

say you have a function like:

```
double do_it(int m)
{
   double result = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
      result += i;

   return result;
}
```

If you know m at compile time you can do:

```
template<size_t t_m>
double do_it()
{
   double result = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < t_m; i++)
      result += i;

   return result;   
}
```

This gives a possibility for things like loop unrolling when optimizing. But, sometimes you might know some cases at compile-time and some at run-time. Or, perhaps you have defaults which a user could change...but it would be nice to optimize the default case.

I'm wondering if there is any way to provide both versions without basically duplicating the code or using a macro?

Note that the above is a toy example to illustrate the point.

Comment: Unrelated: can't you simply `return m*(m-1)*0.5;` ?

Comment: This is a toy example to illustrate the point.

Comment: [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)?

Comment: `constexpr` is not enough.  the compiler can do a lot more optimizations when it knows the code can only be called at compile time then when it could be both compile and run time.

Comment: I knew someone would bring that up :)  So that might work for this toy example, but not in general.

Comment: @NathanOliver : could you kindly elaborate and/or provide references?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar In the template code, the compile knows exactly the loop limit, so it can unroll the loop for small ones and do something else for larger ones.  In the non template code, the compile can't do that because it doesn't know what the limit is.  If you make the non template code `constexpr`, it is still in the same boat because you can call a `constexpr` function at run time.

Comment: @NathanOliver : A brainy compiler is simply going to emit two (or more, if needed) versions of this function - one with the constants folded into the loop's body, potentially eliminating the need for calculating anything altogether, and another one with all stuff evaluated at runtime. [The Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/wf7DX6) seems to agree.

Comment: I just noticed that the runtime version of the function in the compiled code even includes an early return if the runtime parameter's value is the same as the compile-time calculated one.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I think if you want guaranteed compile-time evaluation (also without `-O2`), you need to assign the result to a `constexpr` before returning: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/VGhFHn

Comment: @chtz : Worrying about performance when compiling without optimisation is kind of pointless, no? :-) (the question isn't tagged `language-lawyer`)

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar true, but your example also does not evaluate at compile time with clang for bigger numbers even with `-O3`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/k71W1T

Comment: @BiagioFesta exactly my point ...

Comment: @chtz Ups... I didn't notice I didn't expand all comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, with `std::integral_constant`.  Specifically, the following function will work with an `int`, as well as specializations of `std::integral_constant`.

```
template<class Num>
constexpr double do_it(Num m_unconverted) {
  double result = 0.;
  int m_converted = static_cast<int>(m_unconverted);
  for(int i = 0; i < m_converted; i++){ result += i; }
  return result;
}
```

If you want to call `do_it` with a compile-time constant, then you can use

```
constexpr double result = do_it(std::integral_constant<int, 5>{});
```

Otherwise, it's just

```
double result = do_it(some_number);
```

Comment: Why use `integral_constant` here? It doesn't achieve anything, since you cast it straight to an integer. The only useful part of this answer is `constexpr`

Comment: @Eric labeling the function `constexpr` doesn't particularly matter, and is merely an added bonus.  What matters is that the template parameter can *force* the compiler to create a specialization of `do_it` for every specialization of `std::integral_constant` provided.  In rare situations (specifically, when each specialization is infrequently called, avoiding caching issues), this method improves performance.

Comment: Specifically, this is useful if there is a large function with several runtime arguments, but where one argument might additionally need to be specialized for a small handful of compile-time values.

Answer (score 5):

In terms of the language specification, there's no *general* way to have a function that works in the way you desire. But that doesn't mean compilers can't do it for you.

> This gives a possibility for things like loop unrolling when optimizing.

You say this as though the compiler cannot unroll the loop otherwise.

The reason the compiler can unroll the template loop is because of the confluence of the following:

1. The compiler has the definition of the function. In this case, the function definition is provided (it's a template function, so its definition *has* to be provided).
2. The compiler has the compile-time value of the loop counter. In this case, through the template parameter.

But none of these factors explicitly *require* a template. If the compiler has the definition of a function, and it can determine the compile-time value of the loop counter, then it has 100% of the information needed to unroll that loop.

How it gets this information is irrelevant. It could be an `inline` function (you have to provide the definition) which you call given a compile-time constant as an argument. It could be a `constexpr` function (again, you have to provide the definition) which you call given a compile-time constant as an argument.

This is a matter of quality of implementation, not of language. If compile-time parameters are to ever be a thing, it would be to support things you cannot do otherwise, not to support optimization (or at least, not compiler optimizations). For example, you can't have a function which returns a `std::array` whose length is specified by a regular function parameter rather than a template parameter.

Comment: I marked the integral_constant answer as the chosen answer as it more directly answers the question, but I appreciate the insight of your answer as well and think it forms a more complete picture.

Answer (score 1):

Use `constexpr` (needs at least C++14 to allow `for`):

```
constexpr double do_it(int m)
{
   double result = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
      result += i;

   return result;
}

constexpr double it_result = do_it(10) + 1;  // compile time `do_it`, possibly runtime `+ 1`

int main() {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    do_it(x);  // runtime
}
```

If you want to force a constexpr value to be inlined as part of a runtime expression, you can use [the `FORCE_CT_EVAL` macro from this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248235/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time#comment19851837_14248304):

```
#include <utility>
#define FORCE_CT_EVAL(func) [](){constexpr auto ___expr = func; return std::move(___expr);}()

double it_result = FORCE_CT_EVAL(do_it(10));  // compile time
```

Comment: have you read the comment thread? People have said that `constexpr` is not enough to force the compiler to create a specialization

Comment: @phuclv: If the return value is knowable at compile-time, a specialization is unnecessary - better to inline the return value. Updated with a macro that forces the compiler to evaluate an arbitrary constexpr.