# Override for constant expressions?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading, constexpr

Is it possible to override a function and/or template based on whether something is a constant expression?

Basically what I'd like to do is build a string class that if handed a static string, or a constexpr variable pointing at one, it will simply use that pointer and won't later try to delete it.

On the other hand, if the class is handed a buffer it needs to either copy it or adopt it, and then delete it in the destructor.

I think that the closest possible is to use a strong typedef and require the programmer to declare his/her static strings under that typedef.  I wonder though if those smarter than I can come up with something that doesn't require that.

Comment: Based on your explanation, I do not see why you should treat a file scope array differently from a block scope array. The former is an address constant expression, the latter isn't, but neither should be deleted.

Comment: You mean overload instead of override, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to find out if a passed parameter was originally a constant expression without having the user tell you.

Comment: @Xeo - I'd consider that a viable answer if you made it one.

Comment: Strings are problematic in particular because string literals are always lvalues.

Comment: @Xeo - please make that an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically what I'd like to do is build a string class that if handed a static string, or a constexpr variable pointing at one, it will simply use that pointer and won't later try to delete it.

I think we're facing an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Knowing whether an expression is or is not `constexpr` won't tell you whether or not it is appropriate to `delete`.

I would say the function shouldn't try to guess whether or not to delete if there is a possibility that this action is inappropriate. I believe the caller should take care of that, possibly using smart pointers to *not* take care of that.

In other words, I would let the function accept an lvalue reference, and let the client dereference a pointer if the pointed object must be passed as an argument to the function.

I would say this pattern makes sense not just in the case of `delete`: more generally, if a piece of code has the **responsibility** of deciding how some values should be generated or computed (e.g. object allocation), then also the **responsibility** for correctly carrying out some related or corresponding action (e.g. cleanup) should belong to the same piece of code:

```
void foo(my_object& o)
{
    // ...
}

my_object o;
foo(o);
// The argument has automatic storage, no need to delete

my_object* pO = new my_object();
foo(*pO);

// The argument was allocated through operator new, we must
// deallocate it through a corresponding call to delete
delete pO;
```

If you really want the cleanup to *take place* in the function, you should give the client a way to tell the function how to perform it:

```
void foo(my_object& o, bool shouldDelete)
{
    // ...
    if (shouldDelete) { delete &o; }
}

my_object o;
foo(o, false); // "And don't try to deallocate this object please..."

my_object* pO = new my_object();
foo(*pO, true); // "Please, delete it for me" (we are delegating the
                // responsibility of performing the material action,
                // but not the one of knowing how!)
```

To allow for greater flexibility, you could even accept a callable object, which makes even clearer what I meant in the above comment by "*delegating the responsibility of performing the material action, but not the one of knowing how*":

```
#include <functional>

void foo(my_object& o, std::function<void()> f = [] () { })
{
    // ...
    f();
}

int main()
{
    my_object o;
    foo(o); // "And don't do anything with this object when you're done..."

    my_object* pO = new my_object();
    foo(*pO, [=] () { delete pO; }); // "Please, do exactly this when done..."
}
```

If you do not need to determine the type of the callable object at run-time, you may even consider turning `foo()` into a function *template*.

---

Finally, concerning your original question on how to **determine whether an expression is a constant expression**, this is not possible in general, but there are some techniques which could help you in cetain situations - just be aware of their limitations. In this regard, you may find [**this Q&A on StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299394/is-is-constexpr-possible-in-c11) relevant.

Comment: I quite knowingly asked the question I wanted answered.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: If it is you who downvoted, I would like to get an explanation. Besides pointing out that your approach may fail to determine whether it is safe or not to delete, my answer does also answer your knowingly asked question, in that it points you to the relevant Q&A on how to determine if an expression is a constant expression.