# Can C++ differentiate between a compile time constant and a variable passed to a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I don't think this is possible (at least not as of c++11), but is there a function signature that can differentiate between a passed compile time constant (includes constexpr results that are calculated at compile time) and a variable?

I'm writing a library where this could be useful under some very specific cases and if I can infer these, then the library could save some CPU cycles, without the developer having to do the analysis themselves.

Comment: The short answer is: nope.

Comment: Thanks @BinaryBirchTree.  Didn't find that before.

Comment: @Adrian : At least your title was better. ;-]

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, the slightly longer answer is maybe. :D

Comment: A solution as macro is provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13305072/34509