# How to hide a particular function from the debugger in C++

Tags: c++

I want to hide some functions from the debugger in C++. C# has the `[DebuggerHidden]` tag. Is there any equivalent feature in C++ to hide functions?

Comment: No, there is no such feature in C++

Comment: Remove (`strip`) all debugging information? What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: I believe you means Visual C++?  I doubt this could be part of the ANSI C++ standard.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What do you really want to do?

Comment: I am going to release my Software to client , I want Hide some internal Function from debugger.

Comment: Then create a *release* build, without any debug information (and with optimizations enabled). Without debug information there won't be *any* symbols available for the clients.

Comment: Client also ask for a debug information.So i need this.

Comment: Could you put the specific funtions in a library and compile the lib without debug symbols?

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove, from the PDB(s), symbols for *specific* functions, while still retaining them overall ? And is so, dare I ask what you honestly think you're accomplishing by doing this? Anyone with facilities to wire up the pdb you *do* provide will have no problem wiring up a disassembler to finish the job on their own.Regardless, [`/PDBSTRIPPED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/pdbstripped-strip-private-symbols?view=vs-2015) *might* be long the line of what you're seeking, though I have reservations you want to go that far.

Comment: If you completely want to exclude that function from Debug builds you can surround it by a `#ifdef NDEBUG` and `#endif` macro.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no C# `[DebuggerHidden]` equivalent or even close in C++. And afaik there isn't anything compiler specific either for the major compilers. At least not for specific functions.

---

Somewhat remotely related (ish) is the upcoming C++20 [immediate functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347298/what-is-consteval) (declared with `consteval`) which as far as I can tell will not appear in the binary at all, being entirely a compile-time feature. The fact that there will be no debug information is a side-effect and not the purpose of those so take them as you will. The fact that they can be evaluated only with compile-time parameter expressions makes them even less desirable for your demand.