# C++ run function at compilation time only

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++14, assert, static-assert

`constexpr` might run functions at compilation time. Is there a way to force it to compilation time only?

Sample code:

```
constexpr int BUILD(int i)
{
    static_assert(0 == i);
    i++;
    return i;
}


enum Events
{
    FIRST = BUILD(0)
};
```

The compilation error:
`Error[Pe028]: expression must have a constant value`

**[Edit]** Another example to explain the rationale:

```
constexpr int BUILD(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    static_assert(a < b);
    static_assert(b < c);
    static_assert(c < d);
    static_assert(d < 10);
    return a+b+c+d;
}


enum Events
{
    FIRST = BUILD(0, 4, 6, 9),   //numbers are defined manually
    SECOND = BUILD(2, 3, 7, 8),
    THIRD = BUILD(0, 1, 2, 3),
};
```

Comment: What's the point of the `static_assert`? If I remove it, it compiles for me.

Comment: You can make a function compile-time only with `consteval`. However, you can still not validate a parameter this way.

Comment: @Rulle that's the idea. Think of a complex build that is built half-manually. The `assert` prevents human error

Comment: @Ronen333 Can you give us *the bigger picture* of the actual problem that you are solving? Then we could give better help.

Comment: @BoP unfortunately it doesn't run at C++14

Comment: @Rulle added another example at the post

Comment: why do you want to perform those checks via passing arguments to funcitons?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number added a new example. The idea is to build a complex `enum` at compilation time

Comment: ok, but the issue is that function parameters arent constant  expressions, hence you cannot static assert them. Trying to call the function at compile time is your problem not your solution ;) Its a bit of a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), though both x and y are somewhat clear

Comment: @Ronen333 The short answer is that you can probably replace `static_assert` by an ordinary `assert`.

Answer (score 3):

Function parameters are not constant expressions, hence you cannot static assert on their value.

You can use a template instead. Just to outline the idea, this is one possibility to provoke an error when `i` is not `0`:

```
template <int i, bool = true>
struct BUILD;

template <int i>
struct BUILD<i, i==0> { static constexpr int value = 0;};

enum Events
{
    FIRST = BUILD<0>::value,
    ERROR = BUILD<1>::value
};
```

Here `FIRST` is ok, while `ERROR` triggers:

```
<source>:15:23: error: incomplete type 'BUILD<1>' used in nested name specifier
   15 |     ERROR = BUILD<1>::value
      |                       ^~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such a thing in C++ as a `constexpr` function parameter. It doesn't matter if you pass a `constexpr` argumen t to a function, e.g.

```cpp
constexpr int i = 3;
f(3)
```

the function `f`, the signature of which could be

```cpp
void f(int x)
```

will not know whether the parameter `x` is bound to a `constexpr` argument or not, so you'll not be able to use `x` in `static_assert`.

If you really want to pass compile time args, use metafunctions. Roughly speaking, you change a function *taking some (runtime) arguments* and *returning some value* to a class *templated on corresponding template arguments* and *containing a `static constexpr` member* resolving to the value you want to compute; the body of the function, where you want to assert, becomes the body of the class; then you can also have a template `bool` variable to ease the usage.

So a function like

```cpp
int BUILD(int i)
{
    /*runtime*/assert(0 == i);
    i++;
    return i;
}
```

can become

```cpp
template<int i>
struct BUILD_impl {
    static_assert(0 == i);
    constexpr static bool value = i + 1;
};
template<int i>
constexpr bool BUILD = BUILD_impl<i>::value;
```

[now you'd use `BUILD<0>` instead of `BUILD(0)`](https://godbolt.org/z/4s7ccYMj9).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the the parameter of a function in a `static_assert`, regardless of its modifiers.

I recommend going with a template instead, for similar syntax:

```
namespace Impl
{

constexpr int CalculateBuild(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return a+b+c+d;
}

template<int a, int b, int c, int d>
struct BuildHelper
{
    static constexpr int value = CalculateBuild(a,b,c,d);

    static_assert(a < b, "a < b violated");
    static_assert(b < c, "b < c violated");
    static_assert(c < d, "c < d violated");
    static_assert(d < 10, "d < 10 violated");
};

template<int a, int b, int c, int d>
constexpr int BUILD = BuildHelper<a,b,c,d>::value;

}

using Impl::BUILD;

enum Events
{
    FIRST = BUILD<0, 4, 6, 9>,   //numbers are defined manually
    SECOND = BUILD<2, 3, 7, 8>,
    THIRD = BUILD<0, 1, 2, 3>,

    // ERROR = BUILD<1, 2, 3, 10>

    // uncommenting the above yields something like
    //
    // static_assert failed: 'd < 10 violated'
    //
    // along with some information about which template specialization is responsible
};
```

Answer (score 1):

C++20 introduced immediate functions, that *must* be evaluated at compile time to produce a compile-time constant<sup>1</sup>.

We can also `throw` an exception from there, which results in a compilation error:

```
consteval int BUILD(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if ( not (a < b) ) throw "a should be less than b";  
    if ( not (b < c) ) throw "b should be less than c";  
    if ( not (c < d) ) throw "c should be less than d";  
    if ( not (d < 10) ) throw "d should be less than 10";  

    return a+b+c+d;
}

enum Events
{
    FIRST = BUILD(0, 4, 6, 9), 
    SECOND = BUILD(2, 3, 7, 8),
    THIRD = BUILD(0, 1, 2, 3),
//    ERROR_A = BUILD(5, 4, 6, 9),
//    ERROR_B = BUILD(2, 7, 3, 8),
//    ERROR_C = BUILD(0, 1, 4, 3),
//    ERROR_D = BUILD(0, 1, 2, 13)
};
```

So that, uncommenting say, the C case, we get an error<sup>2</sup> like:

```
<source>:18:15: error: expression is not an integral constant expression
    ERROR_C = BUILD(0, 1, 4, 3),
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:5:24: note: subexpression not valid in a constant expression
    if ( not (c < d) ) throw "c should be less than d";  
                       ^
<source>:18:15: note: in call to 'BUILD(0, 1, 4, 3)'
    ERROR_C = BUILD(0, 1, 4, 3),
              ^
1 error generated.
```

The same works in C++14, using a `constexpr` function<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1) See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval or [What is consteval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347298/what-is-consteval)</sup> 
<sup>2) https://godbolt.org/z/Goc7YrYWr</sup>
<sup>3) https://godbolt.org/z/8b4GqG467</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [Asserts in constexpr functions](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/05/18/asserts-in-constexpr-functions/), you can use `assert` instead of `static_assert` in `constexpr` functions. This works, because only if the assertion fails will a function that is not *constexpr* be called, causing a compilation error.

Or you can implement your own assert `my_constexpr_assert` that is always active whether *debug* mode is turned on or off:

```
void my_assert_fail() {} // NOT Constexpr
#define my_constexpr_assert(expr) if (!(expr)) {my_assert_fail();}
```

The following compiles for me:

```
constexpr int BUILD(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  my_constexpr_assert(a < b);
  my_constexpr_assert(b < c);
  my_constexpr_assert(c < d);
  my_constexpr_assert(d < 10);
  return a+b+c+d;
}

enum Events {
  FIRST = BUILD(0, 4, 6, 9),
  SECOND = BUILD(2, 3, 7, 8),
  THIRD = BUILD(0, 1, 2, 3)
};
```

but if I edit a line to be `THIRD = BUILD(0, 1, 0, 3)` I get the error

```
main.cpp:2:63: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘void my_assert_fail()’
    2 | #define my_constexpr_assert(expr) if (!(expr)) {my_assert_fail();}
      |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
main.cpp:6:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘my_constexpr_assert’
    6 |   my_constexpr_assert(b < c);
```

which is what we expect, claiming that assertion `b < c` failed.

You can replace `my_constexpr_assert` by `assert` from `<cassert>` but I am not sure it will be active when debug mode is turned off.

**Note:** You may want to put an `abort();` in `my_assert_fail` to make sure that it produces an error even when called from a non-constexpr function.