# Attempt to implement is_constexpr() - compilers diverge

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

The following are three attempts to implement `is_constexpr()` based on a [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1041090/richard-smith)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50169108/1137388) to [Is is_constexpr possible in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299394/is-is-constexpr-possible-in-c11)

**Version 1**

```
template <typename T>
bool constexpr is_constexpr_impl_1(const T& x, decltype(int{(x, 0u)})) { return true; }

template <typename T>
bool constexpr is_constexpr_impl_1(const T&, ...) { return false; }

template <typename T>
bool constexpr is_constexpr_1(const T& x) { return is_constexpr_impl_1(x, 0); }
```

**Version 2**

```
template <typename T>
bool constexpr is_constexpr_impl_2(const T& f, decltype(int{(f(0), 0u)})) { return true; }

template <typename T>
bool constexpr is_constexpr_impl_2(const T&, ...) { return false; }

template <typename T>
bool constexpr is_constexpr_2(const T& f) { return is_constexpr_impl_2(f, 0); }
```

**Version 3**

```
template <auto f>
bool constexpr is_constexpr_impl_3(decltype(int{(f(0), 0u)})) { return true; }

template <auto f>
bool constexpr is_constexpr_impl_3(...) { return false; }

template <auto f>
bool constexpr is_constexpr_3() { return is_constexpr_impl_3<f>(0); }
```

I've tested the above (see in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5JRdtP)) with gcc 9.1, clang 8.0.0, icc 19.0.1 and msvc 19.20 and the help of the following functions:

```
void constexpr f_c(int) {}
void f_nc(int) {}
```

Table below shows the expressions I've put in a `static_assert`. I would expect all of them to pass but compilers disagree with me and between themselves (except icc and msvc which agree with one another):

```
                        | gcc  | clang | icc  | msvc |
 is_constexpr_1(0)      | pass | fail  | pass | pass |
 is_constexpr_2(f_c)    | fail | fail  | pass | pass |
!is_constexpr_2(f_nc)   | pass | pass  | fail | fail |
 is_constexpr_3<f_c>()  | pass | pass  | pass | pass |
!is_constexpr_3<f_nc>() | pass | pass  | fail | fail |
```

Who is right and why? (Quotes from the Standard would be useful.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither `is_constexpr_1` nor `is_constexpr_2` are valid because they run afoul of the usual rule that function parameters are not usable in constant expressions. They require `x` and `f`, respectively, to be at least sometimes usable as a constant expression and they never are.

In this case, the [[expr.const]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4.10) restriction of:

> an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either [...]

Doesn't matter what the other two bullets are since we don't have preceding initialization on our *id-expression* that refers to a variable.

`is_constexpr_3` is valid, as Richard Smith explains in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50169108/2069064).

My expectation is:

```
                        | 
 is_constexpr_1(0)      | fail
 is_constexpr_2(f_c)    | fail
!is_constexpr_2(f_nc)   | pass
 is_constexpr_3<f_c>()  | pass
!is_constexpr_3<f_nc>() | pass
```

which is what clang does.