# What is if consteval needed for?

Tags: c++, constexpr, consteval, c++23

C++23 is going to introduce `if consteval`. Where is this going to be used and how does it differ from `constexpr if`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`if consteval` detects if a `constexpr` function is called in a constant expression context. The [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1938r3.html) motivates its introduction for the case where one intends to call a `consteval` function from a `constexpr` function. To understand what that means we consider the following example.

Let's assume we have a `consteval` function `f`:

```
consteval int f( int i )
{ ... }
```

`f` can only be called in a constant expression. On the other hand a `constexpr` function `g` can be called either in a constant expression or at run time. That depends on if the arguments to `g` are known at compile time or not.
Now, calling `f` from `g` if `g` is called at compile time can be done as follows.

```
constexpr int g( int i )
{
  if consteval {    //1
    return f( i );
  }
  else { 
    return fallback();
  }
}
```

Here `if consteval` in line `//1` triggers if `g` is called in a constant expression.
Note that there must be no condition in `//1`. Also the braces after `if consteval` are obligatory.

C++20 introduced [`is_constant_evaluated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated) for detecting whether a function call occurs within a constant-evaluated context. Using `is_constant_evaluated` in our example leads to a subtle bug. I.e. exchanging `//1` by `if constexpr (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {` results in `is_constant_evaluated` to always return `true`.

Comment: This last is because `is_constant_evaluated` isn't giving you information on the entire body of `g()` but on the controlling expression of `if constexpr` ?

Comment: The issue isn't so much that `if constexpr (is_constant_evaluated())` is a bug (it is, but compilers warn, so meh), but that even with `if (is_constant_evaluated())` you cannot call `f(i)` there.

Comment: The thing of constexpr functions is that their constexpr-ness doesn't only depend on their arguments, but also on the context they are being called from. `is_constant_evaluated()` likes `constexpr int x = f(5);` but not `int x = f(5);`.

Comment: and also why cannot we do at least this?  constexpr int g( int i )
{
  if consteval { static_assert( i < ... ); ... } ...
} 

If we know that something is evaluated @ compile time, why not treat the values accordingly?

Comment: Good idea, Alex.