# Detect at compile time if a function is executed in a static context, C++20

Tags: c++, c++20

Can I detect via templates, concepts or in any other constexpr way if a function is being run in a static context? Something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T = SomeTypeIfImStatic_SomeOtherTypeIfImNot>
class FBlah
{
    void foo()
    {
        if constexpr (AmIStatic) { ... } else { ... }
    }
};
```

Alternatively, like this:

```cpp
template <typename T = SomeTypeIfImStatic_SomeOtherTypeIfImNot>
class FBlah
{
};
```

Would like to differentiate between being run in a `static FBlah Blah;` or an `FBlah Blah;` inside of an `FBlah` itself.

I'm aware that I could declare two types, one for static `FBlah` the other for non-static but I'm looking for a compile-time way to do this. I'm using C++20.

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't anything for this.  If we were able to query the storage duration of objects it would definitely allow a lot less bugs to be created.

Comment: I think it would cause more bugs than it would prevent...

Comment: Maybe your are looking for [`std::is_constant_evaluated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated)? Also, as a note, C++23 will have [`if consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Consteval_if). Also compare [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68213013/3740047).

Comment: Do you mean `static` as only this translation unit/cpp file or `static` as class variable or `static` variables inside functions, which are initialized once and keep their value? Your example `static FBlah Blah;` could be all three.

Comment: @Sebastian I was thinking any kind of `static` i.e. the static storage specifier in general but I'm open to suggestions for any and all kinds of statics.

Comment: At runtime you could perhaps detect in `Blah`, whether `this` points to the stack. At compile-time it is more difficult. Preprocessor macros replacing `static` perhaps? Otherwise reflection in C++29? Or can you write the static variable declaration in a way that the constructor is const evaluated for static storage duration?

Comment: The function doesn't know at compile time where it's going to be called from, so I'd say what you're asking for is impossible.