# recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 256

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, recursion, clang

I was trying to rewrite the Factorial implementation using `constexpr` function but for some reason I have no idea why I get a compile error:

> recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 256

Actually I know what the error message means but what I don't is why I'm getting this error and why the code 1 using `struct` work but the second using function doesn't. What's the difference between them?

```
 // yes, I know it doesn't return the factorial value. First I want to make it compile
template <int N>
constexpr int f2()
{
    return N == 0 ? 1 : f2<N - 1>();
}

template <int N> struct Factorial
{
    enum 
    {
        value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value
    };
};

template <> struct Factorial<0>
{
    enum
    {
        value = 1
    };
};


int main() 
{
    x = f2<4>(); // compile error
    n = Factorial<4>::value; // works fine
}
```

Comment: Why are you using constexpr with templates? Why not just pass N in as an argument? Getting rid f templates for this kinda thing is one of the reasons we have constexpr iirc.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG agreed which is what I pointed out in my answer

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: Because to the function I'm writing I need to tell the compiler the parameter is constant and, neither `const` or `constexpr` does it(the way I need to) so I need to use templates parameters instead of. Similar to Nawaz's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789913/how-to-tell-static-assert-that-constexpr-function-arguments-are-const

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a stopping state like the following:

```
template <>
int f2<0>()
{
   return 0;
}
```

since `f2<N - 1>()` has to be instantiated, you have your stopping state in your other case here:

```
template <> struct Factorial<0>
```

But if you are using `constexpr` you don't really need to use templates at all since the whole point is that it will be done at compile time, so turn it into this:

```
constexpr int f2(int n)
{
  return n == 0 ? 1 : (n * f2(n-1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't know it (I'm a bit new to C++)

Comment: (I answered in comments why I'm using templates)

Answer (score 5):

When `N == 0`, the compiler still has to instantiate `f2<-1>` because the function call is present in the code.  When `f<-1>` is instantiated, `f<-2>` is instantiated and so on.  Applying this statement again and again, the compiler will keep recursing through the template until it exceeds the max depth.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a specialization of the template function to stop the recursion at the **compile time** rather than **runtime**, just as your struct version did.

```
template <int N>
int f2()
{
    return N * f2<N - 1>();
}

template <>
int f2<0>()
{
    return 1;
}
```