# What is possible with a non-type template argument in c++ and why is this code unreachable?

Tags: c++, templates

What is possible with a non-type template argument and which limitations does the standard imply?

For example this code exceeds template initalization depth:

```
template<unsigned N>
inline constexpr unsigned fibo_v() {
    if (N == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (N == 1 || N == 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fibo_v<N - 1>() + fibo_v<N - 2>();
    }
}
```

The IDE also tells me, that after N == 0 the code is unreachable.

- How gets N instantiated?
- Why does `if constexpr ()` solve the unconditionally instantiation?

Comment: You need to use specializations, or `if constexpr`. As written, `fibo_v<N - 1>` gets instantiated unconditionally, even when `N == 0`, and so you end up with an infinite recursion.

Comment: Update the title to not be click-bait: that is, make it *relevant* to the actual issue, which is about a *specific* template usage and issue with such.

Comment: It’s not my question. Also, the original problem of “What is possible..?” remains. A better summary might be “Why does this Fibonacci template exceed initialization depth?”, eg. Or focus on another problem as may deemed relevant.

Comment: “What is possible in a program?” (with an associated non-template error) has the same flaw. Not sufficient focus as it asks for a set of ‘all possibilities’.

Comment: [Compiles for me](https://godbolt.org/z/z9SEVH)

Comment: Anything's possible in theory, any limitations are compiler-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `if constexpr` will solve it, but you need to make sure to use it eveywhere, not just on the first `if`:

```
template<unsigned N>
inline constexpr unsigned fibo_v() {
    if constexpr (N == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if constexpr (N == 1 || N == 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fibo_v<N - 1>() + fibo_v<N - 2>();
    }
}
```

As @IgorTandetnik explains: without the `if constexpr`, the compiler treats all parts of the function as valid code that must be compiled, even if it knows that it can't be executed.  This means that it will need to instantiate `fivo_v<N-1>` even when `N==0`.

Comment: Thanks, Can you explain why I have to use constexpr? I do not understand why I get a  "recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth" error message.

Comment: I found an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22800293/3103271