# Fixed-width integer literals in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14, user-defined-literals

C++11 first introduced support for defining new literals into C++ by means of *user-defined literals*. Does C++11 or later also predefine suffixes for fixed-width integer literals for types in `<cstdint>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No.** As of C++14 the only literal suffixes defined by the standard are provided by `<chrono>`, `<complex>` and `<string>` headers in the standard library. The `<chrono>` header defines the `h`, `min`, `s`, `ms`, `us`, `ns` suffixes for time durations, `<complex>` defines the `i`, `il` and `if` suffixes for imaginary numbers, and `<string>` defines the `s` suffix for `basic_string` literals.

However, one can easily define their own fixed-width literals like this:

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr std::int8_t operator "" _int8(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::int8_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uint8_t operator "" _uint8(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uint8_t>(v); }

constexpr std::int16_t operator "" _int16(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::int16_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uint16_t operator "" _uint16(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uint16_t>(v); }

constexpr std::int32_t operator "" _int32(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::int32_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uint32_t operator "" _uint32(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uint32_t>(v); }

constexpr std::int64_t operator "" _int64(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::int64_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uint64_t operator "" _uint64(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uint64_t>(v); }

constexpr std::int_fast8_t operator "" _int_fast8(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::int_fast8_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uint_fast8_t operator "" _uint_fast8(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uint_fast8_t>(v); }

constexpr std::int_fast16_t operator "" _int_fast16(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::int_fast16_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uint_fast16_t operator "" _uint_fast16(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uint_fast16_t>(v); }

constexpr std::int_fast32_t operator "" _int_fast32(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::int_fast32_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uint_fast32_t operator "" _uint_fast32(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uint_fast32_t>(v); }

constexpr std::int_fast64_t operator "" _int_fast64(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::int_fast64_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uint_fast64_t operator "" _uint_fast64(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uint_fast64_t>(v); }

constexpr std::int_least8_t operator "" _int_least8(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::int_least8_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uint_least8_t operator "" _uint_least8(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uint_least8_t>(v); }

constexpr std::int_least16_t operator "" _int_least16(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::int_least16_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uint_least16_t operator "" _uint_least16(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uint_least16_t>(v); }

constexpr std::int_least32_t operator "" _int_least32(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::int_least32_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uint_least32_t operator "" _uint_least32(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uint_least32_t>(v); }

constexpr std::int_least64_t operator "" _int_least64(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::int_least64_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uint_least64_t operator "" _uint_least64(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uint_least64_t>(v); }

constexpr std::intmax_t operator "" _intmax(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::intmax_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uintmax_t operator "" _uintmax(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(v); }

constexpr std::intptr_t operator "" _intptr(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::intptr_t>(v); }

constexpr std::uintptr_t operator "" _uintptr(unsigned long long v)
{ return static_cast<std::uintptr_t>(v); }
```

**Warning:** The above code will silently give the wrong result if used on literals which don't fit into `unsigned long long`, as well as overflow if the literal value, doesn't fit into the requested type, e.g. `999_int8`. A [better implementation](https://github.com/sharemind-sdk/cxxheaders/blob/master/src/CstdintLiterals.h) (GPL-3 licensed) would probably have to parse the literal character-by-character and `static_assert` on overflow, like [this](https://github.com/sharemind-sdk/cxxheaders/blob/master/src/IntegerLiterals.h).

The downside of using user defined literals is that one needs to prefix the suffixes with an underscore `_`, because suffixes without the underscore are reserved for future standardization according to §17.6.4.3.4.

Comment: How about [throwing an exception on overflow, making compilation fail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8626450/256138)?