# How to initialize uint64_t in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

`uint64_t x(1 << 35)` gives the output as `0` with a warning. What would the most appropriate to initialize such large values?

Comment: Use a literal of the right type, the expression `1ULL << 35` won't overflow because the left hand side is a large enough type

Comment: How about `(static_cast<uint64_t>(1) << 35)` ?

Comment: In C++11 and later can also define [new literals for the types in `<cstdint>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406333/fixed-width-integer-literals-in-c) which you can use to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because `1 << 35` is an operation using `int`. If you want 64-bit types then use `1ULL << 35` to make sure it's an operation using `unsigned long long` (which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits).

Answer (score 4):

```
auto x = std::uint64_t(1) << 35;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that the compile time evaluate constant expression 1 << 35 is performed with int types. So it's likely you are overflowing that type and the behaviour is undefined!

The simplest fix is to use 1ULL << 35. An unsigned long long literal must be at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint64_t x = 1000000000ull;
```

The *ull* marks the value as *unsigned long long*

```
int64_t y = 1000000000ll;
```

The same with a normal *long long*.

```
uint64_t x2 = (1ull << 35ull);
```

Simply add *ull* at the end of your number.