# why does static_assert doesn't work inside memberfunctions with const parameter?

Tags: c++

I am currently playing with `static_assert` and came across this problem:

```
class A
{
public:
   void func( const int a ){
      static_assert( a == 3 );
   }
};
```

Gives me:

`error: non-constant condition for static assertion static_assert( a == 3 );`

Why is this? My a is const. I could imagine that the value will be cast to const and was previously non const, then yes an error should appear. But only inside the member function, I wouldn't expect any errors.

How can I solve that? If not solveable I am also glad about an answer, kinda curious here.

Comment: very related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626055/c11-static-assert-within-constexpr-function

Comment: You want `assert()`, not `static_assert()`, for run time assertations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this? My `a` is const.

Because your `a` is not *compile time* const. The error message is not very precise in this regard. The expression of `static_assert` must be compile time constant.

`const` usually declares runtime constness. It ensures that the object won't be modified throughout its lifetime. But the compiler cannot know what value would be used to initialise the argument (i.e. passed to the function) at runtime.

> How can I solve that?

Either don't use `static_assert`, or use a template argument instead of runtime argument (in which case you need to have a function template in the first place). Example:

```
template<int a>
void func(){
   static_assert(a == 3);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The expression in a `static_assert` must be a [compile-time constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression). A `const` function parameter is merely immutable, but not known at compile time.

Comment: it sure is, when I call my function with `func(3)` this is surely a const and this is what I want to do.

Comment: @Dimfred - And what's stopping you from calling the function with `int main(int a, char**) { A{}.func(a); }` ? It's not a compile time constant.

Comment: @Dimfred The function definition must stand on its own.

Comment: @Dimfred Sure, but the code also has to accept `int foo; std::cin >> foo; func(foo);` and that can't work.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I understood it.

Comment: @Dimfred If your argument is always a compile time constant, you can pass it as a template argument if you want to keep it's compile time constness.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, top-level const (and volatile) qualifiers on function parameters are ignored. Try it - you can't have an overload set like

```
void func(int a);
void func(const int a);
```

This is roughly because the top-level type (ie, not the pointed-to-type if the argument is a pointer) is already passed by value, in some sense. (This intuitive argument doesn't exactly work for references, but they're always immutable anyway).

Anyway, even if it really *were* `const` (which it definitely isn't), that's just a promise not to mutate an otherwise runtime-mutable value. It doesn't make it known at compile time.

Consider that this would compile, and even if the argument were `const int &`, that's only a promise that `func` won't mutate `i`. No-one knows the value until the program is run and receives input.

```
int i;
std::cin >> i;
a.func(i);
```

You could instead write

```
template <int a>
void func(){
  static_assert( a == 3 );
}
```

Comment: What is even more fun is you can declare the function as `void func(int a);` and then define it as `void func(const int a) { code }` so you have const correctness in the function.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ce28725d0c1f2c2