# static_assert within constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, avr, c++20, static-assert

I search for a method to detect a given value for a constexpr constructor is in a valid range.

The code is as follows:

```
class Timer0 {

constexpr uint16_t CalcPresecaler( uint32_t faktor )
{   
    uint16_t prescaler = faktor / 255;

    if ( prescaler <    1 ) return    1;  
    if ( prescaler <    8 ) return    8;  
    if ( prescaler <   64 ) return   64; 
    if ( prescaler <  256 ) return  256;
    return 1024;
}   

constexpr uint8_t PrescalerBits( uint16_t prescaler )
{   
    if ( prescaler == 1024 ) return 0b101;
    if ( prescaler ==  256 ) return 0b100;
    if ( prescaler ==   64 ) return 0b011;
    if ( prescaler ==    8 ) return 0b010;
    if ( prescaler ==    1 ) return 0b001;
    return 0b000; // should never happen
}  
    constexpr Timer0( const uint32_t sysclk, const uint32_t timerclk )
    {
        uint32_t faktor = sysclk/timerclk; 
        uint16_t prescaler = CalcPresecaler( faktor );
        uint8_t prescalerBits = PrescalerBits( prescaler );
        uint8_t compare = (faktor/prescaler)-1;
        static_assert( ???? ); << can not be used on function parameters
        OCR0=compare;
        TCCR0=0x08| prescalerBits;
        TIMSK=0x02;
    }
};
```

```
int main()
{
     Timer0 t0(  8000000, 10 );
}
```

I already read [C++11 - static_assert within constexpr function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626055/c11-static-assert-within-constexpr-function)
but I can't use `throw` as I am on a avr embedded target where gcc has not enabled exceptions, even if it used here for compile time checking.

Any idea how to detect at compile time that the value of `compare` did not exceed a given value?

Comment: You could do something illegal maybe? Perhaps `reinterpret_cast` or dereferencing a nullptr?

Comment: @user975989: and how should that be detected at compile time?

Comment: Why not `Timer0Impl<800000, 10> t0`? It's going to be always compile time anyway, right?

Comment: You use `constexpr` function with parameters whose values aren't known at compile time. Is it by intention?

Comment: `if(!condition) *(int*)(nullptr)`? I realize now that you are using `C++20`, so you can just use `consteval`.

Comment: @user975989 making the constructor consteval still reports "the value of 'compare' is not usable in a constant expression"

Comment: @vahancho: Which value is not known at compile time? I have all values at compile time... Don't understand your point

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? As of now there are missing functions.

Comment: What about `OCR0`, etc.?

Comment: @user975989 avr target, these are predefined register names.

Comment: @Klaus, are the function parameters `const uint32_t sysclk` and `const uint32_t timerclk` known at compile time?

Comment: @Klaus have you tried a normal `assert`? It also creates a compile-time error if used in a constexpr context.

Comment: @vahancho: Yes. The constructor is called with constants

Comment: https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/microcontrollers/avr/avr_timer0_generic.h

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot throw, you can do something that is illegal in a constexpr environment.

For example, if your condition is that `prescalerBits != 0`, you can do:

```
if (prescalerBits == 0)
    *(int*)nullptr = 0;
```

Which should stop any compile time evaluation. If you are worried about calling this function at runtime and getting a null pointer dereference, you can guard this condition with `std::is_constant_evaluated()`.

Comment: any chance to detect anf get a compile error in the case that we are not constant evaluated? Can't use it in the context of constexpr if nor in static_assert. So if a lib user calls for non constexpr context, weget no error at all, even if we did not get the nullptr access.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not really self-contained so it is not clear exactly what the problem is, so we will solve similar but simpler problem:

> Construct a rectangle at compile time and check it is not a square
> (lengths of sides must be different).

First one uncomfortable C++ truth:

**There are no constexpr function arguments in C++.**

It is confusing to many developers, including me, but it makes sense when you understand what it would mean, but that is a different long story...

Hack/workaround this it to use template arguments as a way to have "constexpr function arguments".

Simple example:

```
constexpr void fn(const int val){
  // does not compile even when val is 47: fn(47).
  //static assert(val==47);
}

template<auto val>
constexpr void fn_cx(){
  // does  compile  when called with 47:  fn<47>()>
  static_assert(val==47);
}
```

now to [implement](https://godbolt.org/z/ofbr6b) our Rectangle example:

```
class Rectangle{
    public:
    constexpr Rectangle(const int a, const int b): a_(a), b_(b){} 
    template<auto/*you can also use int here*/ a, auto b>
    static constexpr Rectangle MakeCx(){
        static_assert(a!=b,"square not allowed");
        return Rectangle(a,b);
    }
    constexpr int area() const{
        return a_*b_;
    }
    private:
    int a_;
    int b_;
};


int main()
{
    // ok
    constexpr auto rect = Rectangle::MakeCx<2,3>();
    // static_assert fails
    // constexpr auto square = Rectangle::MakeCx<2,2>();
    return rect.area();
}
```

Note: you mention you are using some predefined registers, those obviously can not be written to in constexpr constructor.