# Converting an integer to a bitmask in compile time not using macro

Tags: c++, c++20

TLDR: Provide a "bitmask" class with a constexpr constructor that creates the bitmask based on the input parameter (applying a bitshift) in the compile-time, which could be used instead of a function-like MACRO.

I'm trying to implement an event manager that stores events as bit flags. This would be a wrapper for an RTOS feature such as [event flag group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/rtos/threadx/chapter4#tx_event_flags_create)

I would like to have the events specified this way

```cpp
enum Event
{
    FOO,
    BAR,
    BAZ,
};
```

Not this way:

```cpp
// This construct is harder to maintain and easier to make a mistake
enum Event
{
    FOO = 0b0001,
    BAR = 0b0010,
    BAZ = 0b0100,
};
```

The events would be then used in this way:

```cpp
class EventService
{
    uint32_t current_events;

public:
    void set_event(const EventMask ev)
    {
        current_events |= ev.mask;
    }

    bool check_event(const EventMask ev)
    {
        const bool was_set = current_events & ev.mask != 0;
        current_events &= ~(ev.mask);
        return was_set;
    }

};

EventService s;

void event_producer()
{
    s.set_event(Event::FOO); 
}

void event_handler()
{
    if(s.check_event(Event::FOO))
    {
        // do something;
    }

    if(s.check_event(Event::BAR))
    {
        // do something else;
    }

    if(s.check_event(Event::BAZ))
    {
        // do something else;
    }
}
```

Therefore I've implemented a helper class `EventMask` with constexpr constructor that just makes a bit shift and stores it as a const member.

```cpp
struct EventMask
{    
    const uint32_t mask;

    template<typename Enum>
    constexpr EventMask(Enum event_id) : mask(1u << event_id)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_enum<Enum>::value, "Enum required.");
        constexpr_assert(event_id <= MAX_ID);
    }
};
```

But unfortunately, these bitmask objects are not created in the build-time while using  `check_event` and `set_event`. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/cGqKahz6a) is the whole example put together.

```cpp
set_event(Event::FOO);
check_event(Event::BAZ); //this should fail in the conpile time because I set BAZ to be higher then MAX_ID
```

I know I could have a MACRO wrapper around `set_event` and `check_event` but I believe there is a more modern way (probably I just don't understand the constexpr in the first place.) On the other hand, I could have a template with a template argument `N` and body `1u << N` but this would make the code bloat, wouldn't it?

I've been thinking about `consteval` but this will not allow to send a runtime event (like stored somewhere as a configuration) which appears as a valid usecase

Comment: You tagged this as c++20. You should use consteval

Comment: For the record, I disagree that `enum Event
{
    FOO = 1 << 0,
    BAR = 1 << 1,
    BAZ = 1 << 2,
};` is either error prone or hard to maintain, and is how I would personally handle this.

Comment: replace `set_event` with `operator |=`. Implementing the other bit operators could be useful to.

Comment: `1u << 55` is implementation defined. Your assertion with `MAX_ID` is too late.

Comment: @Taekahn Thanks. I've been thinking about consteval but this will not allow to send a runtime event (like stored somewhere as a configuration). Sorry I've mentioned That in the question.

Comment: @Taekahn `enum Event {     FOO = 1 << 0,     BAR = 1 << 1,     BAZ = 1 << 2, };` That is the construct I'm already using. But I have a record of "refactoring" by renaming and reordering that led to two events having the same mask -_-

Comment: Why would you store the bit number of something instead of the eventmask?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow That is a good question! I need to think about any drawbacks but it seems reasonable. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer why your assertion doesn't work but I avoid the problem with:

```
enum class Bits
{
    FOO,
    BAR,
    BAZ,
};

enum class Event
{
    FOO = 1llu << int(Bits::FOO),
    BAR = 1llu << int(Bits::BAR),
    BAZ = 1llu << int(Bits::BAZ),
};

Event operator |(const Event &lhs, const Event &rhs) {
    return Event(int(lhs) | int(rhs));
}

Event x = Event::FOO | Event::BAR;
```

Lots of boilerplate but it works.

Comment: Thanks, but to avoid such a boilerplate I'm trying to introduce this EvenMask generic class.

Comment: Introspection would solve this problem.