# Is it possible to infer template parameters of tuple from brace-type initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, explicit, copy-initialization

In this example, is it possible to allow the deduction of the template parameters type of the `tuple`?

```
#include<tuple>
#include<string>

template<class T1, class T2>
void fun(std::tuple<T1, T2> t, std::string other){}

int main(){
    fun(std::tuple<double, int>(2.,3), std::string("other")); // ok
    fun(std::make_tuple(2.,3), std::string("other")); // ok, but trying to avoid `make_tuple`
    fun({2.,3},std::string("other")); // desired syntax but
    // giving compilation error: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T1' void fun(std::tuple<T1, T2> t)
}
```

I added the second argument `other` to avoid solutions involving variadic arguments at the level of the function `fun`. Also, I am trying to avoid the use of `make_tuple`, at least from the user code (i.e. in `main()`). In fact it doesn't need to be the `tuple` type the one involved as long as the "desired syntax" is allowed and somehow its element types can be deduced at later stage.

(Also, although similar, this has nothing to do with `initializer_list` since it doesn't work at all having dissimilar elements in the braces)

It fails at least with `clang 3.2` and `gcc 4.7.2`. Is there any hope that it would work with the current or a near-future standard? (e.g. a future(?) `initializer_tuple`.)

(This can be very useful to add expressiveness to function calls, by aggregating subelements, but that can be argued about)

---

Note: For the example code it seems that `std::forward_as_tuple` is more appropriate than `std::make_tuple` so the arguments are not necessarily copied: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple . Still not as nice as if there were a build-in language feature for heterogeneous initializer lists.

Comment: Apparently there is absolutely no way (sic). Anybody has any comment about adding an `initializer_tuple` language feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is absolutely no way. Deduction fails if the element types are not of the same type. And no deduction is done at all if the parameter is not a `std::initializer_list<T>` anyway (you are right that `initializer_list` doesn't have anything to do with the braces you give, but this is the simple rule for deduction to work).

The template parameter values must be deduced by other function parameter positions involving them or must be explicitly specified.

Comment: I interpret that your answer is a statement about the language limitation and not per se a limitation of `tuple` or whatever is implemented in `initializer_list`, right? So, absolutely now way even using other tuple-like type? I'll have to wait until C++2X then it seems.

Answer (score 0):

It is the age of C++20 and there is still no general way to do this.

#### Workaround 1:

There is a partial solution in the case that the bracket syntax it is, for any reason, reserved for a particular combination of arguments: for example

```
template<class T1 = double, class T2 = int>
void fun(std::tuple<T1, T2> t, std::string other){}

int main(){
    fun({2.,3},std::string("other")); // now works at least, but it may not mean what it seems
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xGaEP5EGn

The worst part of this solution is that it lets exchange the double and the int, but I would say that is a problem of the implicit conversions of built-in types.

It works for any version of C++.

#### Workaround 2:

The only change since the OP is that now there is CTAD (class template argument deduction).

Which means that there is a new partial workaround for this problem, which is

```
    fun(std::tuple{2.,3}, std::string("other")); // ok, but still trying to avoid `tuple`
```

#### Fantasy solution:

This inspired me to think that may be this can be done if CTAD is **extended** in the future with one of these syntax:

The natural extension to CTAD is if this worked:

```
void fun(std::tuple t, std::string other){}  // implicitly a template because std::tuple is a template
```

More explicitly:

```
void fun(std::tuple<auto, auto> t, std::string other){}  // implicitly a template because std::tuple is a template and `auto`.
```

or

```
template<template<typename...> class Tuple = std::tuple>
void fun(Tuple t, std::string other){}
```

or

```
template<template<typename...> class Tuple = std::tuple, class T1, class T2>
void fun(Tuple<T1, T2> t, std::string other){}
```

None of these work currently, but I am fond of the first and the last option.
The first because it is an extension of CTAD (the type is moved from the calling point to the function argument).
Besides CTAD has been shown to work with (non deduced) template template classes.

The last because it is template argument deduction, under some expanded definition of deduction.
The default argument can help deduce the template template argument (`std::tuple`).