# Template argument deduction fails when using a braced init expression

Tags: c++, templates, types, template-argument-deduction

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void printPair(const std::pair<T1, T2> &p) {
    std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    printPair({1, 1});
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile that code, the compiler is unable to infer the template arguments to the function `printPair`. If I remove the template code and change the parameter to `std::pair<int,int>` then the code compiles fine. Or I can keep the template and change the call to `printPair(std::make_pair(1, 1))` and it also works fine.

Why can't the template arguments be deduced without using `make_pair`?

Comment: Highly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582667/why-do-auto-and-template-type-deduction-differ-for-braced-initializers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to infer template parameters of tuple from brace-type initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703838/is-it-possible-to-infer-template-parameters-of-tuple-from-brace-type-initializat)

Comment: `{1, 1}` has no type. The only valid deduced type is `std::initializer_list<T>`.