# how to solve template parameter deduce problem?

Tags: c++, c++20

Compiler can not deduce `_t2` and reports this error:

> could not deduce template argument for '_t2'

Any suggestions, without making any changes in `main()`?

```
#include <tuple>

template <
    typename                        _t1,
    template <typename> typename    _t2>
void test(
    _t1                     p1,
    std::tuple<int, _t2>    p2)
{
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    test(
        1,
        {
            2,
            'a'
        });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```template <typename> typename _t2``` means ```_t2``` is a type that has a ```typename``` template parameter. It should just be ```typename _t2```

Comment: @TARN4T1ON, so I get "could not deduce template argument for '_t2'" error...

Comment: When you replace the whole template definition ```template <typename _t1, template <typename> typename _t2>``` with ```template <typename _t1, typename _t2>```? I was talking about the whole second template parameter.

Comment: Since `main()` cannot be changed, this seems to be a duplicate of [Is it possible to infer template parameters of tuple from brace-type initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703838/is-it-possible-to-infer-template-parameters-of-tuple-from-brace-type-initializat)

Comment: @TARN4T1ON, yes... I replaced.

Comment: @DrewDormann similar but not same.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Different place. You have to explicitly call the constructor of ```std::tuple<int, char>``` in the argument passed to ```test```. So either ```std::tuple<int, char>(2, 'a')``` or ```std::tuple<int, char> { 2, 'a' }```, instead of an initializer list.

Comment: @VeNToR The target Drew suggested is exactly the problem you have (once you change the template template parameter to a template parameter as TARN4TION mentioned). Why don't you think it's the same question?

Comment: @cigien, I think that compiler can deduce without using std::make_tuple ?

Comment: No, it can't (well, it could just use a `tuple` constructor, but that's the same thing). Regardless, your question is still the same as the target, right? Take some to read through that post, and see why `{}` can't be used if you want to infer the types.

Comment: Curly braces define an initializer list, which would then have to be implicitly cast to a ```std::tuple```, for which the basic initializer list does not have the necessary conversion function (proper term is cast operator). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: @cigien, I will take a look and re-think, thanks...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
test(
    1,
    {
        2,
        'a'
    });
```

The compiler cannot deduce curly braces. You should change that line to:

```
test(
    1,
    std::make_tuple(
        2,
        'a'
    ));
```

And your function to:

```
template <
    typename                        _t1,
    typename    _t2>
void test(
    _t1                     p1,
    std::tuple<int, _t2>    p2)
{
}
```

Comment: is there any solution without std::make_tuple ?

Comment: Calling the ```std::tuple``` constructor directly. That's also exactly what ```std::make_tuple``` does, actually.

Comment: @VeNtoR I don't think so, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

Comment: @TARN4T1ON Yes, you are right, but that is just longer and nastier: std::make_tuple(2,'a') versus std::tuple<int, char>(2, 'a')

Comment: @TyceBrown, I've been memorized en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple already :)