# Is there a way to enforce full initialization of std::array

Tags: arrays, c++11, initialization, stdarray

I am using `std::array<size_t, N>` (N is a fixed template-variable).

```
#include<array>
template<size_t N>
struct A{
   size_t function(std::array<size_t, N> arr){ return arr[N-1];} // just an example
};

int main(){
   A<5> a;
   a.function({{1,2,3,4,5}}));
}
```

And it works fine. The problem is that this other code is silently allowed:

```
   A.function({{1,2,3}}));
```

That is, even with missed elements the `array` is initialized somehow, even if it is well defined (e.g. remaining elements initialized to zero, I am not sure) this is a possible source of errors.

**Is there a way to enforce the initialization of the extra elements?** E.g. by generating a compiler error or a warning.

One option that I contemplated is to use `initializer_list`

```
   size_t function2(std::initializer_list<size_t> il){ assert(il.size() == N); ...}
```

The problem is that this generated a runtime error at best and a check in every call. I would prefer a compiler error/warning.

I am not so much bothered by the default initialization of `std::array<>{}` but by the *incomplete* initialization. (Maybe there is nothing it can be done about it, since this is inherited from the behavior of `T[N]` static array.)

I tried using `clang 3.5` and `gcc 5`.

Comment: @texasbruce, thanks, I tried that. The problem is that `N` in `std::array<size_t, N>` cannot be inferred from the argument (at least in my compiler), and from there on `std::enable_if` doesn't help. Or you mean something different?

Comment: I misinterpreted your question. enable_if won't help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: You cannot.

When initializing `std::array` with a list, it is doing an `aggregate initialization`, and it is explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) when the list size is less than the number of member:

- If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members are initialized by their brace-or-equal initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14) by empty lists, which performs value-initialization. If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed (references cannot be value-initialized)

It is simply a legal and acceptable behavior to provide less than the size list, so compiler will not complain anything. Your code:

```
A<5> a;
a.function({{1,2,3}}));
```

is equivalent to:

```
A<5> a;
a.function({{1,2,3,0,0}}));
```

to compiler. Your best bet is runtime error (which may not be as you wished).

Comment: I guess that a runtime check is also not possible because how can one distinguish a real zero from an omitted zero for example. Changing to initializer list is a different work around.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it is formally correct, the other answers are good workarounds.

Answer (score 7):

You can enforce this by using parameter pack, but with a bit different syntax:

```
#include <array>

template<size_t N>
struct A{
   template<typename... T>
   size_t function(T&&... nums)
   {
     static_assert(sizeof...(nums) == N, "Wrong number of arguments");
     std::array<size_t, N> arr = { std::forward<size_t>(nums)... };
     return arr[N-1];
   }
};

int main(){
   A<5> a;
   a.function(1,2,3,4,5); // OK
   a.function(1,2,4,5);   // Compile-time error
}
```

But, I think there is no good way to enforce that in compile time. I would just use `assert(il.size() == N)` in production code to check size of initializer list.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wrapper for your objects

```
template <class T>
struct WrapT
{
    WrapT() = delete;

    WrapT(T e)   : value(e){}

   public: T value; 
   // or add some operator()
};
```

and

```
size_t function(std::array<WrapT<size_t>, N> arr){ return arr[N-1].value;}
```

so a function call like (with full brace-init)

```
function({ {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}} });
```

will not compile because of use of deleted function. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbd79ab5dc4c3bb3). The syntax is a little clumsy, and even then I'm not sure all the possible value-initialization cases are covered.

@dpy points out you may omit the innermost ones, so you get to your original code: `function( {{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }} )`.

Comment: This made me understand that the problem is not only of `std::array` but also of the element type. This answer very conceptual because it tells me that I maybe should use an explicitly initalized type. In `clang` I don't need the extra bracket around each element for some reason.

Comment: WrapT can have automatic conversion `operator T&()` and `operator T const&() const`. Also I can define `template<class T, size_t N>
using initialized_array = std::array<WrapT<T>, N>;` and use it as `... function(initialized_array<size_t, N> arr){...}`.

Comment: You can use brace-elision, this restores the OP's `{{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }}` syntax. The first `{` initializes the `std::array`, the second one initializes `std::array`'s internal C-style array (X), then we have a `1` which is not a `{` so brace-elision applies. The members of (X), i.e. the `WrapT<size_t>` elements are each initialized from a single initializer `1`, `2` and so on. This works because `WrapT(T e)` allows implicit conversions.

Comment: @dyp Thanks for that; updated. For some reason GCC complained and wanted the full syntax.