# Initializer List construction and static assert

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I'm trying to get my class to support initializer lists.

```
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

template <class value_type, size_t Size>
class Queue {
    std::array<value_type,Size> m_data;
    size_t m_last_write;

public:
    Queue(std::initializer_list<value_type> list) :
        m_last_write(0)
    {
        static_assert( list.size() <= Size, "Initializer list length is longer than Queue has been configured for");

        for (auto& datum : list)
            push(datum);
    }

    void push(const value_type& val)
    {
        if (++m_last_write >= Size);
            m_last_write -= Size;

        m_data[ next_i ] = val;
    }
};
```

Everything works well here except for the `static_assert`. Where I get:

> error: non-constant condition for static assertion
>
> error: ‘list’ is not a constant expression

This sounds like the same issue that [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438671/static-assert-on-initializer-listsize) ran into.

One of the proposed solutions there suggests this as the answer:

```
template<size_t N>
Queue(const value_type(&list)[N] ) :
    m_last_write(0)
{
    static_assert( N <= Size , "Too big!" );

    for (auto& datum: list)
        push(datum);
}
```

However, when I use this initializer list:

```
Queue<int,10> r = {66,55,44};
```

I get this error:

> error: could not convert ‘{66, 55, 44}’ from < brace-enclosed initializer list> to Queue< int, 10ul>

Comment: You cannot use `static_assert` for something that will be known at runtime only. How about throwing an exception instead?

Comment: The last example I give (which avoids std::initializer_list) should be deduced at compile-time.

Comment: argument are not `constexpr`, and we cannot know size from the *type* `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused between `brace-enclosed initializer list` and `std::initializer_list`.  I understand that `std::initializer_list::size` isn't `constexpr`, so perhaps I'm trying to use `brace-enclosed initializer list` as if it were a `std::initializer_list` even though they are entirely independent.

Comment: Note that `std::initializer_list::size` is `constexpr` since c++14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of solution you posted is that in the [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), i.e. `Queue<int,10> r = {66,55,44};`, the constructors of `Queue` are considered in overload resolution to match the three arguments `66`, `55`, `44`, then the match fails.

You can add two more braces as the workaround, then the argument `{66,55,44}` will be used as one argument to match the constructors' parameter; then it matches the one takes an array and works as expected.

```
Queue<int,10> r = {{66,55,44}};
```