# Is it possible in C++ to have a variable number of parameters be specialized by the template value?

Tags: c++, templates, initializer-list

Say I have the following template class:

```
template<int R> class dummy{
    public:
        // functions
    private:
        int arr[R];
};
```

Is it possible to create a constructor that accepts exactly R number of parameters that are to be used to initialize the `array`?

Something used like this:

```
dummy<3> a(1,2,3); // where array[0] is set to 1, array[1] is set to 2, and so on...
```

I know how to achieve the same result with this:

```
template<int R> class dummy{
    public:
        dummy(const int(&list)[R]){
            for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) arr[i] = list[i];
        }
    private:
        int arr[R];
};
```

Then use it:

```
dummy<3> a({1,2,3});    // OK
dummy<3> b({1,2});      // also OK but arr[2] will be set to 0
dummy<3> c({1,2,3,4});  // compile-time error
```

The issue is I want a compile time guarantee that the list being passed is exactly the size R, not bigger, not smaller. The compiler for the above code will complain if the list is larger, but not if smaller.

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438671/static-assert-on-initializer-listsize) but the size there is automatically determined by the function call and the hardcoded value of 3 is part of the assertion. I can't use static_assert because R will always be the value set by the class initialization (e.g., `dummy<3>` sets `R=3` and the constructor call will fill the list with 0s if it is smaller than 3).

How to guarantee the number of passed arguments is exactly R at compile time?

Comment: Wouldn't a `static_assert` work in your case? If not, please elaborate.

Comment: I already put that in the question. It won't work when the passed list is smaller than R because the compiler will automatically fill the rest of the list to match the size R. With that said, `static_assert` is still not usable because there is no value other than R it can compare with.

Comment: The _"is smaller than R"_ part I buy. About: _"Say I have the following template class:

template<int R> class dummy{
    public:
        // functions
    private:
        int arr[R];
};
Is it possible to create a constructor that accepts exactly R number of parameters that are to be used to initialize the array?"_ - Yes - exact match? No CTAD I assume.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the compiler will always fill the missing values with 0s, so I may have to accept that given `static_assert` is not going to be usable as I explained earlier.

Comment: What about something like `template<class... T, typename=std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(T)==R>> dummy(T... args) : arr{args...} {}`?

Comment: And you can use `std::initiatlizer_list<R> list` directly and e.g. check [list.size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/size) in `static_assert`

Comment: @dewaffled that does not work, `list.size()` cannot be resolved during compile time, it is only resolved at runtime.

Comment: @Evg I tested that, it achieved the first result I was looking for! I am looking further into doing the assignment within the function's body instead of using `: arr{args...}`, thanks!

Comment: @Everyone _"the compiler will always fill the missing values with 0s"_  - what? No, why? I always use my class `foo` in benchmarking. It's good. '0' doesn't cut it.

Comment: You can do it in the function body with a (standard) trick: `std::size_t i = 0; ((arr[i++] = args), ...);`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo when I tested it with multiple initializer lists that were undersized, the remaining values were filled with 0.

Comment: @Everyone Please show a [mre]. Show the expected output - and the output you unexpectedly get.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's written in the question... `dummy<3> b({1,2});      // also OK but arr[2] will be set to 0`

Comment: @Everyone I'm glad you got the information you needed. Regarding _"it's written in the question"_ - Please read up on [mre].

Comment: @TedLyngmo i honestly don't know what you are asking me to provide aside from what I have provided. The code I have in the question (template class dummy with initializer list) will produce an array that has a `arr[2]=0` when used with `dummy<3> b({1,2});` as also provided in the question. Are you asking me to add `main()` around the function call `dummy<3> b({1,2});`? I didn't even say it was a problem, just an observation...

Comment: @Everyone _"i honestly don't know...."_  - Ok, a [mre] just means exactly what the information says. It's nothing special,. Everything not needed to reproduce the problem. Nothing more, nothing less. The fact that you got lucky this time doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `static_assert()` works well if you make the constructor parameterized. Working example: https://godbolt.org/z/dcP683cdh

```
#include <cstddef>

template <int R>
class dummy {
 public:
  template <size_t N>
  explicit dummy(const int (&list)[N]) {
    static_assert(N == R);
    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
      arr[i] = list[i];
  }

 private:
  int arr[R];
};

dummy<3> a({1, 2, 3});
dummy<3> b({1, 2});
dummy<3> c({1, 2, 3, 4});

int main() {}
```

Comment: Well, it works! Thank you. The suggestion by @Evg also worked so now I have two solutions and I may be using both haha.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer based on the feedback from Evg as the alternative solution other than the accepted one, in case somebody wanted the other method that creates a constructor with exactly R parameters:

```
template<int R> class dummy {
    public:
      dummy<R>() {}
        template<class... T, typename = std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(T) == R>> dummy(T... args) {
            size_t i = 0; 
            // iterate through the arguments method - useful if using types other than int[] as the data behind
            for (const auto val : {args...}) {
              arr[i++] = val;
            }
        }

    private:
      int arr[R];
};
```

Then it can be used like this:

```
dummy<5> a(1,2,3,4,5);    // OK
dummy<5> b(1,2,3,4,5,6);  // COMPILER ERROR
dummy<5> c(1,2,3,4);      // COMPILER ERROR
```

Comment: You might further restrict `T` to be convertible into `int`. Also note that this code won't work with non-copyable types like `std::unique_ptr`. You'll need to get rid of initializer list in `for` to support them.

Comment: @Evg that's a good idea, and great point with the unique_ptr point. I honestly am willing to delete this answer if you are willing to post one that you see more complete. You deserve it.

Answer (score 1):

Using C++20 concepts, you can achieve it without using raw arrays at all,:

```
#include <concepts>
template<std::size_t N>
class dummy{
public:
    template<std::convertible_to<int> ... Targs>
        requires (N == sizeof...(Targs))
    dummy::dummy(Targs&& ... vargs)
    : arr{std::forward<Targs>(vargs)...} {};
private:
    std::array<int, N> arr;
};

template<std::convertible_to<int> ... Targs>
dummy(Targs&& ... vargs)->dummy<sizeof...(Targs)>;// CTAD

dummy a{1,2,3};         //CTAD: dummy<3> a;
auto  b = dummy{1,2};   //CTAD: dummy<2> b;
dummy<5> c {1,2,3,4,5}; //explicit construction 
//dummy<4> d{1,2};      //compile error
```

The construction syntax becomes a bit cleaner.

Comment: How many other STL containers does this apply to? Say, `vector` or `valarray` or others, for example?

Comment: @Everyone `std::array` is actually the most twisted one, because of aggregate initialization. The rest of containers are constructible from `std::initializer_list`. Moreover, `std::array` is currently the only statically-sized container in std; the rest are dynamically-sized and accept virtually any number of elements (provided the platform can allocate them at runtime as well as compiletime). So, for other containers you can just provide a single argument of `std::initializer_list`. But I prefer the C++23 `std::from_range` constructors and pass `std::array` as input, BC it can be `constexpr`.